# Test for multiple values in an if statement in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, if-statement

Is there a shorthand syntax in C# to make this:

```
if ((x == 1) || (x==2) || (x==5) || (x==13) || (x==14))
```

... shorter? Something like (hypothetically)

```
if (x in {1, 2, 5, 13, 14})
```

I "feel" like it exists, I'm just coming up short mentally and Googly. In reality I have to test a bunch of enums frequently and it's just unreadable. I also hate to make a little helper function if the language supports it already.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

There are clever solutions involving lists... but I was hoping for a pure logical construct of some kind. If it doesn't exist, so be it. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907299/c-sharp-if-statements-matching-multiple-values

Comment: It is not necessary to use inner quotes: `if ( x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 5...)` except if you have used Pascal/Delphi several years and has "professional distortion".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((new[]{1, 2, 5, 13, 14}).Contains(x)) ...
```

Comment: Yeah... I suppose that would be slightly cleaner than what I have. In the absence of a super-simple syntax, I just use a helper function like 3907299 that "Jeremy D" posted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `HashSet<T>` would be faster than `Array`! =)

Answer (score 2):

Though I think the if statement is fine, and making code brief for breifness's sake is useless, here goes:

First approach, assuming you want to go the LINQ route:

```
if ((new[]{1,2,5,13,14}).Contains(x)){
}
```

Second approach, ArrayList

```
if ((new System.Collections.ArrayList(new[]{1,2,5,13,14})).Contains(x)){
}
```

Third approach, List:

```
if ((new System.Collections.Generic.List<Int32>(new[]{1,2,5,13,14})).Contains(x)){
}
```

But keep in mind **all of these** add more overhead (and really don't add much as far as readability, given the performance consideration).

oh, and [working example of the above](http://ideone.com/Ohx9B).

Comment: Good point about the overhead. This will run far more often than I need to read it.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend using [HashSet(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to check whether the element belongs to the set of elements.

Furthermore, as `HashSet<T>` is an associative container, its lookup complexity is O(1), i.e. constant time: [HashSet(Of T).Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx), while `Array` and `List<T>` has linear time lookup: O(n). So, `HashSet<T>` would be the better for lookup.

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 5, 13, 14 };
int x = 1;
if (numbers.Contains(x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for comparing directly like that. However, you could use LINQ methods such as Contains(). I could provide an example but it sort of depends how the data items are originally stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
if( Array.LastIndexOf(new int[]{1, 2,3,4}, x) != -1)
{
    //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Not tested, but I believe this would work.

*edit*
Looks like a similar response has already been posted.