# C# If condition with values check

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm looking for short coding style for the `if` condition containing multiple expression.

Let's suppose, I want to add `if` condition in a string variable name `str`.
Here is my `if` condition.

```
if(str == "a" || str == "b" || str == "c" || str == "d")
```

I want to make this `if` condition short something like that.

```
if(str == "a" || "b" || "c" || "d")
```

or

```
if (str in {"a", "b", "c", "d"})
```

I don't have to put `str ==` again and again.

I know, I can do this using multiple ways:

- Using switch statement
- Making array/list of string and use LINQ or Contains to check.

I want to do some something similar to `if(str == "a" || "b" || "c" || "d")` or `if (str in {"a", "b", "c", "d"})`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is **NO** such syntax available. This is the simple answer to your requirement.

OR

You can follow what **Dmitry Bychenko** suggested in comments.

```
if (new [] {"a", "b", "c", "b"}.Contains(str)) { ... }
```

Check these for more details:

[C# syntax shorthand for multiple condition testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208685/c-sharp-syntax-shorthand-for-multiple-condition-testing)

[Test for multiple values in an if statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594649/test-for-multiple-values-in-an-if-statement-in-c-sharp)

Comment: As per @Dai, That solution results in an extra heap allocation (for the array) on every call which would hamper performance in tight-loop scenarios.

Comment: @Saadi: Sure, but it's really easy to extract that out into a static variable instead, so it's only allocated once.

Comment: @Saadi you can declare that array at class level if values are fixed and also if values are coming from service or DB, you can initialize it at one time in class. Then there will not be any allocation on every call. Just think in detail before you ask this. This is not that major issue. Now a day, all PC/Laptop got good amount of memory and the scenario you put in question is not of enterprise level application where you need to take care of many things. Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Who and why downvoted? I really want to know reason of it. Its find it not removing downvote. Give me a proper reason.

Comment: Writing the code is one thing. Maintaining and reading it later is another thing. I would prefer to keep things easy to understand and readable. I would prefer having multiple `str` over a new array. (I did not downvote)

Comment: So we have to create new array every time while checking using such `if` condition !!

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do this.**

Normally in `if` statement you check for Boolean type.

so 
`if(str == "a")` this checks `str == "a"` and returns `true` or `false` based on value of `str`.

but when you are doing

`if(str == "a" || "b" || "c" || "d")`

what you are actually doing `if( (str == "a") || ("b") || ("c") || ("d") )`

In this instruction, first part is returning Boolean, but others are not returning Boolean, which is not valid for `if` statement.

same way you cannot do following too.

```
int a = 5, b = 6, c = 7;
if(a == b == c) //This is not valid statement
{
}
```

here it will be

`((a == b) == c)` ,and `(a == b)` results into `true` or `false`. so in second part check will be,

`(true/false == c)` , here you cannot compare Boolean with int and cannot provide Boolean result.

> I want to do some something similar to if(str == "a" || "b" || "c" || "d") or if (str in {"a", "b", "c", "d"})

as we have seen, we can't do `if(str == "a" || "b" || "c" || "d")`.

But if you have liberty to have a `List of strings` which does carry all string elements. You need to create a class level (global) list and check in if condition, you can do as below.

lets say `listOfElements` is such list you have.

`if(listOfElements.Contains(str))`