# How to Convert big IF condition to small

Tags: c#

I have to implement a very big If and else statement in a short and smarter way.

for example :

```
If(seg.status =="hl"||seg.status =="hl2"||seg.status =="hl3"||seg.status =="hl4"||seg.status =="hl4"||seg.status =="hl5"||seg.status =="hl6"||seg.status =="hl7")
```

into small and smarter way

Comment: You could use the `In` extension method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: possible duplicate of [if statements matching multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907299/if-statements-matching-multiple-values)

Answer (score 5):

How about adding all your `hl` strings in a `List<string>` and check with [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `Contains` like;

```
var list = new List<string>(){"hl", "hl1", "hl2", ...};
if(!list.Any(seg.status.Contains))
```

As Jon warned, this will return `true` if your string doesn't match with status, choose

```
if(list.Contains(seg.status))
```

instead.

Comment: That's an odd way of writing `if (list.Contains(seg.status))` (In fact, it's not quite doing the write thing at the moment... your condition would match a status of "boringstuffhlotherboringstuff" whereas the original condition wouldn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right Jon, sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I would put them into a HashSet:

```
var keywords = new HashSet<String>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
               {
                  "h1", "hl2", ...
               }
```

And then check if it contains the given word:

```
if(keywords.Contains(seg.status))
{
   // ToDo: What shall happen?
}
```

Comment: what would be the difference using list ? better performance ?

Comment: @utility: Yes, just performance, but in case of 10 elements this doesn't matter. But IMHO the type `HashSet` also better describes for what these elements are used for: For fast lookup where order doesn't matter, a list instead would be my preference if order would matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch(seg.status, @"hl\d*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var segList = new List<string>(){"hl", "hl1", "hl2","hl4", "hl15", "hl6","hl7"};

If(segList.contains(seg.status))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you do this in many places? If so, you could write a little string extension class to make the code more tidy:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool MatchesAnyOf(this string text, params string[] targets)
    {
        return targets.Any(target => string.Compare(text, target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
    }
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
if (seg.status.MatchesAnyOf("hl", "hl1", "hl2","hl4", "hl15", "hl6","hl7"))
```

(If you want a case-sensitive comparison, remove the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter from `string.Compare()`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident on the pattern of the test variables naming:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new Regex("hl[1|2|3|4|5|6|7]");
string[] test=  {"hl1","hl2","hl3","hl4","hl5","hl6","hl7","hlasdfasdf"};
for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++){
    System.Console.WriteLine(test[i] + ":" + (re.IsMatch(test[i])?"match":"does not match"));
}
```

So in your case:

```
   if(re.IsMatch(seg.status)){ //...  }
```