# C# Commutativity in if statements

Tags: c#, coding-efficiency, commutativity

Is there a way to essentially write "and vice versa" in an if statement without writing the same code again but with "||"?

```
if (currentDirection == 1 && nextDirection == 2)
if ((currentDirection == 1 && nextDirection == 2) || (currentDirection == 2 && nextDirection == 1))
```

For example, here I would like it to also be true if currentDirection == 2 and nextDirection == 1 but it seems like there should be a better way to write the code than just the second way.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907299/if-statements-matching-multiple-values

Comment: I don't think that's what "commutativity" means. I think it means you can switch the two halves of a single `==` expression around and get the same result...

Comment: Agree this is not commutativity you are asking for. Your "second way" of writing the code is good and I don't think you should "feel" like its not well written (also btw I only see *one* way that works). Possibly you could design a better way of dealing with "directions" but that's another question.

Comment: There is no such thing as "better" in programming. There is faster. There is "more maintainable". There is "easier to test". Sometimes you get all three in one. Mostly you get one or two at once.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would argue "more maintainable" is often as slippery as "better", too.

Comment: @CameronLindo No the way you have it is the best way. Far better than either answer IMO in terms of maintainability/readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in language construct for this, as it seems pretty niche.

You can easily make a helper function though:

```cs
bool UnorderedEq<T>(T a1, T a2, T b1, T b2) =>
    (a1, a2).Equals((b1, b2)) || (a1, a2).Equals((b2, b1));
```

If you care about performance, then this version for structs is probably better:

```cs
bool UnorderedEq<T>(in T a1, in T a2, in T b1, in T b2) where T: struct, IEquatable<T> =>
    (a1, a2).Equals((b1, b2)) || (a1, a2).Equals((b2, b1));
```

Answer (score 0):

if, and only if, both comparands are guaranteed multiples of two you can do it with a straight and fast bitwise or:

```
    // as extension
        bool static BitMatch(this int bitMask, int val1, int val2)
        => val1 != 0 && val2 != 0 && bitMask!= 0 && ((val1 | val2) == bitMask);
    
    // call
       if ((1|2).BitMatch(currentDirection, nextDirection);
```