# Is a HashSet<T> the same as List<T> but with uniqueness?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to have an ability to have unique items in a collection.

I was going to use a Dictionary so I could use the ContainsKey method but I thought it would be a waste as I wouldnt use the Value property of the Key/Value pair.

I came across the `HashSet<T>` which looks very promising. The only thing I can find that I can't find in the `List<T>` docs is that `HashSet<T>` is unordered. I think that is fine, I assume it means its not ordered using a `IEqualityComparer`. As long as the order in which items are added are in the same index position I think it will be ok as I have to do duplicate checking hence the hashset and then check all entries are sequential.

Is there anything else I have missed comparing the two types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HashSet<T> and List<T> in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, importantly `HashSet<T>` doesn't have any concept of ordering or indexing - a list conceptually has slots 0....n-1, whereas a set is "just a set".

> I think that is fine, I assume it means its not ordered using a IEqualityComparer.

`IEqualityComparer` isn't used for ordering anyway - it *only* talks about equality and hash codes. `HashSet<T>` isn't ordered by *either* an element comparison (as, say, `SortedSet<T>` is) *or* insertion order.

> As long as the order in which items are added are in the same index position I think it will be ok.

There *is* no index position, and when you iterate over a `HashSet<T>` there's no guarantee you'll get them back in the order in which you added them. If you're even *thinking* about ordering, `HashSet<T>` isn't what you're after.

Then again, all of this is *also* true of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - you shouldn't make any assumptions about ordering there, either.

Comment: @Jon: No, but you could write one. It could potentially be backed by a `List<T>` for ordering *and* a `HashSet<T>` for uniqueness.

Comment: @Jon - It's not perfect but the `OrderedDictionary` maintains the inserted order while also giving you fast lookups based on keys... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx  It's not a Generic collection, which kind of sucks.  And the Value parameter would be a waste in your case.

Answer (score 9):

This is a 'picture' of what a `List<T>` looks like:

```
List:  |a|b|r|t|i|p|c|y|z|...
Index: |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|...
```

The `List<T>` represents, well, a list of items. You can refer to an item by its position in the list.

This is a 'picture' of what a `HashSet<T>` looks like:

```
Set:    |a|b|c| | | | | |i| | | | | | |p| |r| |t| | | | |y|z|
Bucket: |a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|
```

The `HashSet<T>` represents a set of unique items. Every item has its own 'bucket'. You can refer to an item by its bucket. The bucket that an item belongs in is calculated directly from an item.

One of the advantages of using a `HashSet` over a `List` is constant-time searches. In a `List`, an item could be anywhere in the `List`, so to find it, you need to look at every item in the `List`. In a `HashSet`, there is only one possible location for any given item. Therefore, to search for an item, all you need to do is look in its bucket. If it's there, it's there, if it's not, it's not.

The illustrations may not be 100% accurate (for simplicity's sake). Especially the `HashSet` example.

Answer (score 6):

No. A `HashSet` doesn’t allow access via index because the items aren’t ordered. This does *not* mean, as you suspect, that they aren’t ordered according to some `IEqualityComparer`. It means that they are *not* stored inside the hash set in the order of adding them.

So if you need an order preserving or random access container, `HashSet` is not for you.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain that I need a Collection<T> so I can check for duplicates and then assuming the order is kept I need to check that all values are sequential.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is what you're after:

```
class UniqueList<T> : Collection<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (!base.Contains(item))
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }
        else
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `UniqueList.Add` will add an item to the end of the list, and will not add duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

You got it slightly wrong. Neither `Dictionary` nor `HashSet` preserves the order of the items, this means you can't rely on the item index. Theoretically you can use LINQ `ElementAt()`  to access item by index, but again both collections do not gurantee that order is preserved.

.NET provides an `OrderedDictionary` class, but it is not generic so you would not have a type safety at compile time. Anyways it allows accessing items by index.

Here is a custom implementation of the generic one: [OrderedDictionary(of T): A generic implementation of IOrderedDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO). The key point: it persists two collections -- `List` and `Dictionary` at the same time; List provides access by index and `Dictionary` provides fast access by a key.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain that I need a Collection<T> so I can check for duplicates and then assuming the order is kept I need to check that all values are sequential.

Comment: @Jon: take a look at the OrderedDictionary class

Answer (score 1):

Well `HashSet` conceptually is a `List` of unique values, but in difference from `List<T>` it doesn't actually implements `IList` interface, but implements `ICollection`. 
Plus it has a set of special functions, like :

`Intersection`, `IsSubsetOf`, `IsSupersetOf`, `Union,` which `List<T>` doesn't have.

These functions, naturally, are handy in operations on multiple `HasSet`s.