# Search in string list and return as bool

Tags: c#, list

I got a `List<string>` named `Test`:

```
List<string> Test = new List<string>();
```

I want to add a string to it using `Test.Add();`, but first I want to check if it already exists in the list.

I thought of something like this:

```
if (Test.Find("Teststring") != true)
{
   Test.Add("Teststring");
}
```

However, this returns an error.

Comment: do you really want to add duplicate values.

Comment: Didn't see that, guess I'm dumb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you  if you don't want to add the item if it is already added

Try This:

```
if (!Test.Contains("Teststring"))
{
   Test.Add("Teststring");
}
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted, but `Contains` is the correct way to check if list contains item

Comment: He actually wants to add it to the array IF it's already there, for some reason... I'm not the one who downvoted, but that might be why.

Comment: @Tobberoth ah, I see now. I believe its just wrong attempt to check if item not exist.. Otherwise how OP will add first item? :)

Comment: i think OP wants to add item if its not added.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: yes but if OP wants to add item if it is already added then he can not add it first time itself right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my mistake. I actually do want to add the item only if it is not there already, guess I'm dumb and didn't check twice

Comment: @2111windows : okay :) hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

[Any](http://www.dotnetperls.com/any) receives a Predicate. It determines if any element in a collection matches a certain condition. You could do this imperatively, using a loop construct. But the Any extension method provides another way.
See this:

```
bool b1 = Test.Any(item => item == "Teststring");
```

Also you can use :

```
if (!Test.Contains("Teststring"))
{
...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add an item twice it is a good indicator that you might use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which is more efficient but doesn't allow duplicates(like a `Dictionary` with only keys).

```
HashSet<string> Test = new HashSet<string>();
bool newString = Test.Add("Teststring");
```

If you need to use the list use [`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the string is already in the list.

[What is the difference between HashSet and List in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt-in-c)

But your code suggests that you only want to add duplicates. I assume that this is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

**In my opinion you are using the wrong datastructure here.** You should use [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid duplicates.

The lookup time for Hashset is O(1) whereas for list it is O(n)

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

This is how your code should look like.

```
HashSet<string> Test = new HashSet<string>();
Test.Add("Teststring");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test.Contains("TestString");`