# Choosing the correct C# collection to use

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object that contains a list of child objects.
This is a very simple Order -> OrderLines type of relationship.

Now I'm trying to map out my class and have set up the object as an ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<OrderLines> OrderLinesCollection { get; set; }
```

However when I assign values to the collection, I am unsure on whether to use a HashSet or a List to hold my collection of OrderLines.

```
this.OrderLinesCollection = new HashSet<OrderLines>();
this.OrderLinesCollection = new List<OrderLines>();
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: It depends on what kind of operations you want to do on the collection.

Comment: the best way depens on your needs. what do you need ? a HashSet or a List ?

Comment: They are two very different data structures and the right one to choose depends on how you want to use them. Read up on what is a `List` and what is a `HashSet` and you'll be able to choose by yourself.

Comment: Does `OrderLines` override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`? If the insertion order is relevant or you want to access via index you should use a `List<T>` (or `T[]`). If the order doesn't matter and you want to find it quickly (or have faster `Contains`-check) use a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: As, above however, you should consider whether you want to expose the property. I would have have a private List/ Hashset (Dictionary) and then a public getter of ICollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice between a `List<T>` and a `HashSet<T>` is straightforward:

- If you need to maintain a specific order of iteration, use a `List<T>`
- If you do not need a specific order of iteration, and you need a fast lookup, use `HashSet<T>`

Note that in order to be usable in a `HashSet<OrderLine>` your `OrderLine` objects must implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. Strictly speaking, they should do it anyway, but for hash-based containers it's a must.

Also note that exposing a setter of `OrderLinesCollection` as a public member puts you in a position where the choice of the container is not entirely up to you: anyone using your class could potentially set `OrderLinesCollection` to a `HashSet` or to a `List`, depending on their preferences. Unless you make the setter `private`, your class needs to be ready to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you requirements. If the order is important, use a `List`, if you often need to check if an item is contained in the collection, use a `HashSet`.
A `HashSet` doesn't respect the order of the items.

For more information see for example this post: [What is the difference between HashSet<T> and List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to think about your use case

From msdn: The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

In my view a list is used when you have to add/delete elements.

So ask yourself, are you going to be adding/deleting elemnts? Is your data set going to have duplicate elements? If neither is the case and you just need something to hold your data, i would use an Array