# Replace duplicates in array of strings

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following `strings = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d" };`

How would you replace the duplicate items to produce the following output: `{ "a", "Duplicate", "Duplicate", "b", "Duplicate", "c", "Duplicate", "Duplicate", "Duplicate", "d" }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For something like this, particularly if you intend to modify the array and not produce a new sequence, I would prefer an old fashioned loop. It would seem to me to be more obvious, less "clever," and easier to understand. If you are of a similar opinion, the loop is fairly easy to write. Create a set that will hold distinct items, and replace items that have already been added to the set.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    if (set.Contains(strings[i]))
    {
        strings[i] = "Duplicate";
    }
    else
    {
        set.Add(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Given your input, your output would be:

```
a
Duplicate
Duplicate
b
Duplicate
c
Duplicate
Duplicate
Duplicate
d
```

Comment: Just wanted to write this down. IMHO this should be the right answer.

Comment: Good anti LINQ overuse answer! But to make it even better comparable to the "elegant" LINQ way in the other answer, the loop body can be reduced to `if (!set.Add(strings[i])) strings[i] = "Duplicate";`

Comment: Bit off-topic: What are the pros and cons of using HashSet instead of eg. Array or List in this example?

Comment: @Jenyoin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt

Answer (score 4):

Using `Linq`, you could do this.

```
s = s.GroupBy(x=>x)
     .SelectMany(x=>x.Take(1)                                    // Take first element
                     .Concat(x.Skip(1).Select(r=>"Duplicate"))   // Replace other elements with 'Duplicate' 
                )
    .ToArray();
```

Check Working [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X8SgqU)

Comment: Very elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @nik0lias, may be elegant(I personally don't find this code elegant. Take this code and show somebody and ask him what does it do without debugging), but I suspect this will be inefficient comparing to straightforward methods.

Comment: @nik0lias Elegant? I make it a habit of asking c# candidates in their interviews about what these fancy Linq statements actually _do_. Let's just say that from the many hundreds of candidates that I've talked with, I have yet to interview the first person that actually _knows_ what statements like this one do under the hood. IMHO that's pretty much the definition of a 'bad practice'.

Comment: I'd question those who didn't have an idea of what the above statement is doing.  I wouldn't implement that unless I had an idea of the queries behind it.  I don't just blindly type LINQ queries nor do I expect others to.  If you understand it then it's elegant (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

In case you are searching for a method which will mark only consecutive duplicates:

```
var strings = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d" };
var output = new string[strings.Length];
output[0] = strings[0];

for(int i = 1; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    output[i] = strings[i] != strings[i - 1] ? strings[i] : "duplicate";
}
```

Comment: What if the input array is not a sorted array?.

Comment: Just want to let you know that OP not mentioned it is ordered list.

Comment: @HariPrasad, it has not have to be sorted in case he wants `only consecutive duplicates`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
strings = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d" };
var myArray = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

foreach(var item in strings){
    if (!myArray.Contains(item))
        myArray.Add(item);
    else
        myArray.Add('Duplicate');
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: `ArrayList` is not a preferred collection to use in modern C#, there are better choices. Secondly, this solution will become increasingly slow as the size of `strings` grows, it will not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought on writing a lambda expression for this

```
var output = strings.ToList().Select((x, y) => Array.IndexOf(strings, x) == y ? x : "Duplicate");
```