# Determine if a string is a vb.net keyword

Tags: vb.net

Is there a simple way to determine if a string (i.e. "Dim") is a keyword
for VB.NET.

I could create a list of keywords, and loop through them, but I was hoping
for something more reliable.

Comment: Store a list with VB's keywords, then check `If myKeywordList.Contains("Dim")`. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409611.aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: thanks for the tip mate

Comment: @AlexM. : What are the odds that we post pretty much the same answer? ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent who knows, maybe you should calculate the probability of it ;) - Might take you 1*10^100 iterations lol.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do this, so you have to maintain your own list.

Depending on how you intend to use it, a [**`HashSet(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) could be used to provide better performance than a `List(Of T)` or an array.

Microsoft has got a list of VB.NET's Keywords [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409611.aspx).

Comment: I personally think an array would be better for this sort of thing - a constant defined in the class as it would be a fixed array and it wouldn't change, supposed, for what they need. Despite what I mentioned in the comment on the question.

Comment: @AlexM. : However the issue with an array or a `List(Of T)` is that to check if an object exists you would have to iterate the list (which `Contains()` does). This causes the operation to be `O(n)`, whereas in a `HashSet(Of T)` you calculate the hash of the object and check if it exists (which has the operation `O(1)`).

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. I'll have to look into `HashSet`, I suppose.

Comment: @AlexM. : Some interesting posts: [**\[ 1 \]**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt), [**\[ 2 \]**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance), [**\[ 3 \]**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4558802/3740093).