# Hashing performance in a HashSet<int> against a List<int> with Contains

Tags: c#, performance, hash, hashset

**I am looking for a comparison/performance considerations between a list of integers against a hash set of integers**. This is what [What is the difference between HashSet<T> and List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt) talks about for `T` as integer.

I will have up to several thousand integers, and I want to find out, for individual integers, whether they are contained in this set.

Now of course this screams for a hash set, but I wonder whether hashing is beneficial here, since they are just integers to start with. Would hashing them first not add unnecessary overhead here?

Or in other words: **Is using a hash set beneficial, even for sets of integers?**

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: _"Now of course this screams for a hash set, but I wonder whether hashing is beneficial here, since they are just integers to start with"_ suggests a lack of understanding how lookups differ between the two. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391896/3181933) or perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391813/3181933) from the question you linked seems to have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have, in the meantime, for a specific case, but I was looking for more comprehensive information. I have a set of 38317 integers and I am doing 9 lookups. This gave an improvement of about 22% in my case. (Measured with Visual Studio 2017 Profiler).

Comment: You might want to check the integer implementation of [`GetHashCode`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,86)

Comment: @Marcel Why wouldn't a HashSet be beneficial for integers? If you add strings to a `HashSet`, they are partitioned using the `.GetHashCode()` method, and then when you do `.Contains()`, etc. with a string, it first looks it up with the hashcode and checks for equality. With integers the difference is that the hashCode == the integer value, although that's an implementation detail. Either way, it works in the same way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This actually answers my question. So, no cpu cycles are lost for hashing, because there is no hashing. :-o

Comment: People really dislike performance questions for some reason.

Comment: @TheodorZouliasYeah. And I guess it's a bit symptomatic that the question is actually only bad worded, (my bad) and not really about the actual performance of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashing an integer is very cheap, as you can see in the source code of the [`Int32.GetHashCode`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/int32.cs.html#2d2b91f1bdc71dbb) method:

```
// The absolute value of the int contained.
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return m_value;
}
```

The hash of the number is the number itself. It can't get any cheaper than that. So there is no reason to be concerned about the overhead. Put your numbers in a `HashSet`, and enjoy searching with [O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) computational complexity.

Comment: This gives me the comfort I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

What ever T is there is a simple but efficient rule of thumb:

- The collection is mainly used for adding and iterating with very few
  search => Use List
- The collection is heavely used for research => Use HashSet

Comment: Yes I know, but my question comes out of the fact that the hash actually is an integer anyway.