# C# Collection/List - Unique ID

Tags: c#, list

In C# I'm trying to create a list of objects and when a new thing is added to the list, it is checked to make sure the same ID isn't used. I have the solution in Linq but I'm trying to do it without linq.

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (students == null)                               
            {
                students.Add(student);                          
            }
            else
            {
                if ((students.Count(s => s.Id == student.Id)) == 1)   

                  // LINQ query, student id is unique
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Error student " 
                  + student.Name + " is already in the class");
            }
            else
            {
                students.Add(student);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first line will throw an error if students is null.

Comment: what type is students  ?

Comment: I think your first line should be `if (students.Count == 0)` assuming you are working with a `List`

Comment: Any reason you're not using a Dictionary?

Comment: A note on the existing code: Get into the habit of using _Any()_ instead of _Count() == 1_ and similar constructs, that can give you great performance improvements once you go into various abstraction frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach would be to use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`.

The `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
    private int id;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Student otherStudent = obj as Student;
        if (otherStudent !=null)
        {
            return this.id.Equals(otherStudent.id);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

}
```

Then you can add stuff like this

```
    HashSet<Student> hashSetOfStudents = new HashSet<Student>();
    Student s1 = new Student() { Id = 1 };
    Student s2 = new Student() { Id = 2 };
    Student s3 = new Student() { Id = 2 };

    hashSetOfStudents.Add(s1);
    hashSetOfStudents.Add(s2);
    hashSetOfStudents.Add(s3);
```

The addition of `s3` will fail because it has the same `Id` as `s2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `Student.Equals()` and `Student.GetHashCode()` to check if the Student.Id is equal. If the student list inherits from `List<Student>`, you can just use the default `Add()` method. It will only add students with different Ids.

```
public class Student
{
    // ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
            return false;

        Student other = obj as Student;
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class StudentList : List<Student> { }

// Usage:

var students = new StudentList();
students.Add(student);
```

Answer (score 1):

A list of distinct items sounds awfully lot like a [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx)

Update: Writing up a good motivation for how to select proper datastructures got a bit tedious, I'll just show you how you will write the above once you are more familiar with the .NET framework:

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    /* this.students is an ISet<Student> */
    if (!this.students.Add(student))
    {
       throw new ArgumentException("student");
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that *Student* has a suitable definition of *Equals()* and *GetHashCode()*. Depending on the concrete ISet type used you may actually get some nice side effects with a good definition of *GetHashCode()*, but that discussion is probably a bit out of the scope for this question.

Comment: It will also need a suitable implementation of `GetHashCode`.

Comment: For reference, the implementation of `ISet<T>` that you will likely want to use will be `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

```
students Dictionary<int, Student> = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
```

then check to see if you already have that student

```
if (!students.ContainsKey(student.id))
{
      students.add(student.id, student);
}
```

Comment: It's not so much a `Map` as it is a `Set`, so `HashSet` would be more appropriate.

Comment: ok whats the diff between the two ? HashSet is faster with lots of data but other than that why ?

Comment: Actually, a HashSet really isn't faster, a `Dictionary` is implemented through the same computer science concept of a hash table that `HashSet` is (not to be confused with the C# type `HashTable`, which, is just a non-generic Dictionary.  The difference is that a Dictionary (which is a "map") maps a Key in a set of keys to a Value; a Set is just a set of values.  You can think of a Map as a Set of KeyValuePairs (which is effectively how it is implemented).  The difference is more logical, and conceptual; you don't need a set of IDs and a set of students, you just need a set of students.

Comment: sounds great so how would you make sure they are unique then ?

Comment: You would override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `Student` intelligently, i.e. for `Equals` compare their IDs and for `GetHashCode` just return the hash of the ID.  `HashSet` will take care of the rest.  If it doesn't make sense to override those methods, or if it's not possible, one can just create a comparer to give to the Set.

Comment: HashSet is faster with large amounts of data - btw  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance

Comment: Of course it will be faster than a list, I never said otherwise.  I said it wouldn't be noticeably different than a `Dictionary`, as they have approximately the same implementation.

Comment: but isn't that kind of logic natively part of a `Dictionary` without overriding anything?

Comment: @Brad It's not natively a part of `Dictionary`, it's natively a part of `int`, if you decide to use that as a key.  The amount of code would be pretty similar in either case, the point is that a Set would logically represent what is going on, unlike a Dictionary, because logically there isn't a mapping of information, there is simply a single set.

Comment: Ah it clicked! That does make sense.

Comment: @Servy I posted your idea as an answer (didn't look like you were going to :) but feel free to edit) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13145889/726127

Comment: @Brad I upvoted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13145041/1159478) as I feel it contained all of the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `foreach` loop:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (students == null)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var s in students)
            {
                if (student.Id == s.Id)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Error student "
                    + student.Name + " is already in the class");
                }
            }
            students.Add(student);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that, here a two possible solutions

### 1. You can iterate through your list.

```
bool alreadyInList = false;
foreach (var item in students) 
{
 if (item.Id == student.Id)
 {
    alreadyInList = true;
    break; // break the loop
 }
}

if (!alreadyInList)
{
   students.Add(student);
} 
else
{
     throw new ArgumentException("Error student " 
              + student.Name + " is already in the class");
}
```

### 2. Override the `Equals` method in you `Student` object and check using `Contains`.

```
public class Student 
{
    public override bool Equals(object x) 
    {
        return ((Student)x).Id == this.Id;
    }
}

if (!students.Contains(student)) 
{
   students.Add(student);
} 
else 
{
     throw new ArgumentException("Error student " 
              + student.Name + " is already in the class");
}
```

More Information:

- [MSDN - Object.Equals Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)
- [MSDN - List.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thank you. Thanks everyone else too.

Comment: @dknaack This isn't really a good implementation; Lists weren't designed to be efficiently searched the way a set-based data structure would be, such as a HashSet or a Dictionary.  Those solutions while they look similar at first glance, end up running substantially more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Make the structure to hold the students be a `dictionary<int,Student>` and check to see if the ID is already in the dictionary via [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

First read all available id's into a `list` or `array` and then make sure that new id's don't match existing id's by checking `list` or `array`.