# List vs Dictionary (Hashtable)

Tags: c#, .net

This may be a silly question but I am reading about that `Hashtables` and `Dictionaries` are faster than a list because they index the items with keys.

I know a `List` or `Array` is for elements without values, and a `Dictionary` is for elements with values. So I would think that it maybe be smart to have a `Dictionary` with the value that you need as a key and the value equal in all of them?

**Update**:

Based on the comments what I think I need is a `HashSet`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance) talks about their performance.

Comment: `Hashtables and Dictionarys are faster than a list`. Depends on what you do with them.

Comment: A [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) would provide the functionality that you are thinking with using a `Dictionary` and using the keys but not the values.  The issue with that is they must be unique, but you'd have had the same thing using a `Dictionray`

Comment: `"value that you need as a key"` this won't be possible if you have duplicate values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Faster" depends on what you need them for.

A .NET `List` is just a slab of continuous memory (this in *not* a linked list), which makes it extremely efficient to access sequentially (especially when you consider the effects of caching and prefetching of modern CPUs) or "randomly" trough a known **integer** index. Searching or inserting elements (especially in the middle) - not so much.

`Dictionary` is an associative data structure - a key can be anything hashable (not just integer index), but elements are not sorted in a "meaningful" way and the access through the known key is not as fast as `List`'s integer index.

So, pick the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

There are some weaknesses to Dictionary/Hashtable vs a List/array as well:

- You have to compute the hash value of the object with each lookup.
- For small collections, iterating through the array can be faster than computing that hash, especially because a hash is not guaranteed to be unique<sup>1</sup>.
- They are not as good at iterating over the list of items.
- They are not very good at storing duplicate entries (sometimes you legitimately want a value to show in an array more than once)
- Sometimes a type does not have a good key to associate with it

Use what fits the situation. Sometimes that will be a list or an array. Sometimes it will be a Dictionary. You should almost never use a `HashTable` any more (prefer `Dictionary<KeyType, Object>` if you really don't know what type you're storing).

<sub><sup>1</sup>It usually is unique, but because there is a small potential for collisions the collection must check the bucket after computing the hash value.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Your statement "list or array is for elements without values, and dictionary is for elements with values", is not strictly true.

More accurately, a List is a collection of elements, and a Hashtable or Dictionary is a collection of elements along with a unique key to be used to access each one.

Use a list for collections of a very few elements, or when you will only need to access the entire collection, not a single element of the collection.

Use a Hashtable or Dictionary when the collection is large and/or when you will need to find/access individual members of the collection.