# Remove from list by index when index is not contained in another list

Tags: c#, list, perf

Is there a way to make this code more efficient ?

```
if (includeRows != null && includeRows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = aList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!includeRows.Exists(j => j == (i + 1)))
        {
            aList.RemoveAt(i);
            includeRows.Remove(i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i did , the aList contains objects not integers , so need the index of the object in the list.Not sure if the includeRows.Remove() would make it less or more efficient, includeRows was just changed to a HashSet.

```
for (int i = aList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (!includeRows.Contains(i + 1) )
                    {
                        aList.RemoveAt(i);
                       // includeRows.Remove(i + 1);
                    }
 }
```

Comment: so you have a list of indexes and you want to remove from another list the items that are not contained in the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on p.s.w.g's answer, I would do:

```
HashSet<int> includeRowsFaster = new HashSet<int>(includeRows);
aList.RemoveAll(i => !includeRowsFaster.Contains(i + 1));
```

for most efficient performance and readibility. Looking for an element in includeRows is an O(n) complexity operation. You can reduce it significantly to O(log(n)) by using a hashset instead of a vector (array or list) implementation.

See this for a discussion on Hashset vs. List performance : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762995/390330

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy way with Linq's [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method:

```
aList = aList.Intersect(includeRows).ToList();
```

But for better performance you can use [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) instead

```
aList.RemoveAll(i => !includeRows.Exists(j => j == (i + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks good answer. Intersect is a good idea , didnt think of that, but will stick with RemoveAll.

Answer (score 0):

```
aList = aList.Intersect(includeRows).ToList<int>();
```