# String comparion against a set of string values

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a function like this(foo): I need to compare the input string and perform a task accordingly . 
Task is same, but only for a selected set of values. For all other values do nothing.

```
function foo(string x)

{
if(x == "abc")
    //do Task1

if(x == "efg")
    //do Task1
if(x == "hij")
    //do Task1
if(x == "lmn")
    //do Task1
}
```

Is there any other means to do checking other than this? Or putting `OR` operator inside `if`?

What is the preferred way?

Comment: The [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx) statement is a good fit for such cases; it allows you to write the target values nicely separated and with a minimum of unnecessary boilerplate.

Comment: A switch statement doesn't really make much of a difference here IMO.

Comment: Enter your comparisons in to a list or collection and iterate over that collection and check inside the for loop and track which collection entry matches.  Also I would not do == on string comparisons I would use the .Equals extension method

Comment: Some people are partial to `if (new[] {"abc", "efg", "hij", "lmn"}.Contains(x)) { Task1(); }`... Not sure myself, but it works.

Comment: The hashset lookup is very nice because it lends itself to easy refactoring; once you realize you should have data-driven it in the first place.

Comment: @anaximander Good one. But it is interesting that `string[]` does not actually contain a method `Contains`, so that works only because of Linq. Not that that is a problem. The pure array solution would be `if (Array.IndexOf(new[] {"abc", "efg", "hij", "lmn"}, x) != -1) { ... }`, but that looks quite awful.

Comment: Are you just looking for some nice in-line syntax? If so, you can always make an extension method that gives you syntax like `if(x.Is("abc", "efg", "hij", "lmn")) { }`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Indeed. I should perhaps have mentioned that it requires Linq, but I build database-driven software so I'm so used to having it available. Come to think of it, I can't remember the last C# program I saw that didn't use it somewhere...

Comment: Thanks to everyone. 
Since array of string doesnt have a "contains" method by itself, i should define an extension method myself or include LINQ namespace. Otherwise i have to use "List"(collections). But i have a list of 10 strings to compared. At max it can grow to 50 strings which is a rare possiblity. In that is it better to stick with array of strings?

Comment: @anaximander Doenst your solution require extension methods of Linq. To make use of lambda function. Like the solution though:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it. One would be as follows:

```
var target = new HashSet<string>{ "abc", "efg", "lmn" };
if (target.Contains(x)) {
    ...
}
```

> At max [my list of strings] can grow to 50 strings which is a rare possibility.

Then you should make `target` a `static readonly` in your class, like this:

```
private static readonly StringTargets = new HashSet<string>{ "abc", "efg", "lmn" };
```

Doing so would ensure that the set is created only once, and is not re-created each time the execution goes through the method that uses it.

Comment: +1 I'd say this is a better alternative to the `if` than the `switch`, with the `switch` you are still pretty much writing the same amount of code.

Comment: Agreed, also depending on the amount of comparison entries you are putting in there it could be faster to go with a List VS a hashset, but as your list of comparisons grows I think hashset offers better performance. see this post here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance

Comment: I think the nicest thing about this is that it lets you easily move `target` into some class or provider and do `if(BusinessRulesFooClass.Something(x))`. In fact, depending on the scenario it's possible it should have been like that all along...

Comment: Since array of string doesnt have a "contains" method by itself, i should define an extension method myself or include LINQ namespace. Otherwise i have to use "List"(collections). But i have a list of 10 strings to compared. At max it can grow to 50 strings which is a rare possiblity. In that is it better to stick with array of strings?

Comment: `using System.Linq` and you're good to go. No custom extensions necessary.

Comment: @NOOB If the array could grow to 50, then you should definitely keep the hash set: it is going to be significantly faster - I'd say about ten times or more, depending on the exact strings. Make the hash set a `static readonly`.

Comment: 50 is very rare possiblity. In the near immediate future even 10 is imporbable.

Comment: @NOOB You should still get about three times speed improvement with ten strings. Making it static ensures that the set object is not re-created each time the code goes through the method. Making it readonly is a way to show to the readers of your code that you are not planning to replace the instance of the set after initialization. This enables additional optimizations in the compiler.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. This seems like a perfect fit for the situation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight . I am not able to make the hashset variable a private static readonly. The compiler is showing errors. Please advice

Comment: @NOOB What error do you get? As any `static` variable, it needs to be defined outside of the method, and its declaration may not use `var`. Copy-paste the second code snippet from the answer outside your method, and it should work. I assume that you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file, too.

Answer (score 7):

do it like this

```
function foo(string x)
{
  switch(x)
  {
      case "abc":
      case "efg":
      case "hij":
      case "lmn":
        {
          //do task 1
          break;
        }
      default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can do this

```
if(x == "abc"||x == "efg"||x == "hij"||x == "lmn")
   //do Task1
```

Comment: Implementation of switch case in this fashion might be a better solution for me i think.

Comment: Will this cause the comparsion operation to be done against all the cases? Rather than do the task on finding the first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make an array of the acceptable strings, then see if that array contains x

```
function foo(string x)

{


     string[] strings = new string[] {"abc", "efg", "hij", "lmn"};

     if (strings.contains(x)){
        //do task 1
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a switch statement with a default value to catch anything that didn't match

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/08/14/50227.aspx

```
function foo(string x) {

    switch(x) {

     case "abc":
      //do task 1
     break;

     case "efg":
      //do task 2
     break;

     default:
      //all other cases
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to perform the same task not different tasks (Task1 on all of them, not task 1 on one and task 2 on the other)

Comment: Answer is in right direction, but formatted wrong...probably misunderstood the question...