# Best lookup data structure to store only the keys (Dictionary without value)

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, dictionary

What is the best data structure in .Net with high performance lookup, like a binary tree implementation, but to store only the keys (string keys) ?

We need only to check if a certain key is present in the collection. Like:

```
Dictonary<string, object> myKeys;
myKeys.Add("key1", null);
myKeys.Add("key2", null);
// Dozens or hundreds keys

Assert.IsTrue(myKeys.Contains("key1"));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in `System.Collections.Generic`):

> HashSet is an unordered collection containing unique elements. It has
>   the standard collection operations Add, Remove, Contains, but since it
>   uses a hash-based implementation, these operation are O(1).

e.g.

```
    HashSet<int> evenNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
    HashSet<int> oddNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Populate numbers with just even numbers.
        evenNumbers.Add(i * 2);

        // Populate oddNumbers with just odd numbers.
        oddNumbers.Add((i * 2) + 1);
    }

    if (evenNumbers.Contains(2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 is even.");
    }
```

- [Introducing HashSet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/11/09/introducing-hashset-t-kim-hamilton.aspx?Redirected=true)
- [HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)

Comment: HashSet documentation (http://goo.gl/wu9xlh) just says it's a "a set of values", nothing more in remarks, nothing about the algorithm. Although we could assume its implementation as a "hash-based" by its name, so it could be O(1) if well implemented, why are you sure about this ? How to get and be sure about this ? Disassembling ?

Comment: @Luciano: If you check the documentation for [HashSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) and [HashSet.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) (and the rest of the methods), you'll see remarks describing the algorithmic complexity. In particular, `Contains` is O(1), and `Add` is O(1) as long as the internal array doesn't have to be resized.

Comment: @JimMischel: Diffuse but sure, is there. Thanks by the help.