# Is there a better data structure than dictionary for key existence

Tags: c#

I often want to optimize the performance of a `.Contains` on a collection.

I have always done this by creating a `Dictionary<TKey,bool>` and then using .ContainsKey on the dictionary to give O(1) `.Contains` performance.

However it always irks me that I actually don't care at all about the value in the dictionary.

**Is there a better data structure than dictionary to support this case where I don't care about the actual value, only the existence of the key?**

Comment: Is your list sorted? If not, is sorting your list once before you check an option?

Comment: @Szymon I could sort it, but it would still be slower than using a dictionary. I think binary search is O(log(n)) which is bigger than O(1) for hash table lookups

Comment: Just as a note O(1) doesn't mean that it's faster necessarily, only that the access to each item is constant.

Comment: @kevin you're absolutely right (eg small collections) however for my application I'm normally dealing with large sets

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482848/best-lookup-data-structure-to-store-only-the-keys-dictionary-without-value you can even search google before asking in SO

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a method [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is an O(1) search of the values. This should suffice (assuming your `TKey` implements `GetHashCode` correctly) :)

Comment: This is way better, exactly what im looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Xenolightning: Good answer. If I may add a detail: AFAIK, `TKey` needs to implement both `GetHashCode` *and* `Equals` correctly, not just the former. (`GetHashCode` by itself only suffices to determine inequality of two objects, but when two objects have the same hash code, that doesn't always mean that they're equal. In that case, only a full equality comparison via `Equals` will tell.)

Comment: @stakx Yeah, you're absolutely right. `GetHashCode` is used for the initial look at where the object should be, `Equals` is then used if something exists in it's slot. Thanks for that clarification.