# For Loop - Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, for-loop, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Actually,I got a requirement like `save in Db` the `combinations of 9 digit number` in encrypted format.

So,I have used a very basic algorithm for encryption and thought of using for loop until `999,999,999` and save the records in `DataTable` and `BulkCopy to SQL`.

My Program goes like this :

```
DataTable DtData = new DataTable();
DtData.Columns.Add("ENCRYPTED_DATA", typeof(string));        

for (Int64 i = 1; i <= 999999999; i++)
{
    string Number = i.ToString("D9");

    string Encrypt = EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(Number);

    DtData.Rows.Add(Encrypt);

    if (i % 100000 == 0)
    {
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }
}
```

But my problem is I'm getting `out of memory exception` after some time.
Is there a way to `Garbage Collect` or some other way and save the Memory Consumption?
Actually the Code of `GC.Collect` is not at all reducing the Memory Usage as I can see in TaskManager.

My `PC RAM is 16GB` and the approximate time taken for processing `8,000,000 records is 7 minutes`.
After consuming 16GB it is giving out `OutOfMemoryException` as per TaskManager.
Is there a way to reduce the MemoryConsumption and make my forloop fully execute?

Comment: you are running out of memory because you are running out of memory.  What are you expecting??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

does not free the data already in `DataTable DtData`. I don't know the size of strings that you are creating but you are creating thousands of strings and adding them to `DataTable DtData`.

These strings in `DtData` are never eligible for Garbage Collection within the scope of this loop.

You should periodically commit the numbers to the database as in the following

```
DataTable DtData = new DataTable();
DtData.Columns.Add("ENCRYPTED_DATA", typeof(string));        

for (Int64 i = 1; i <= 999999999; i++)
{
    string Number = i.ToString("D9");

    string Encrypt = EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(Number);

    DtData.Rows.Add(Encrypt);

    //vary this number depending on your performance testing and application needs
    if (i % 100000 == 0)
    {
        //instead of this 
        //GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);


        //commit changes and refresh your DataTable

        DoSomeDatabaseCommitHere(DtData);
        DtData = new DataTable();

    }
}
```

You also can employ a [Collection class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc79sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DataTable` for more options and asynchronous uploading.

Comment: Yes.I'm going to try that.Thank you for supporting

Comment: As I've calculated it will take more than 17 hours for completing the whole cycle. Is there a way to make it fast? Instead of DataTable,If I use a List,will it help?

Comment: A list should be faster, though a HashSet may be even more performant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance for more info on List vs HashSet. Possibly also modify the line `if (i % 100000 == 0)` to a larger number to have fewer bulk commits. In addition, you can look at using background threads for commiting while encrypting. See my link regarding various Collection classes that would assist with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your DtData is filling up and taking all your memory.

All the garbage collection in the world isn't going to help.

Save your data now and then to the database and empty the DtData DataTable.

Comment: ok.Will try to save the Records to DB in if (i % 100000 == 0) condition and clear the DataTable.