# List.Add vs HashSet.Add for small collections in c#

Tags: c#, performance, list, set

Given

```
HashSet<T> set;
List<T> list;
T t;
```

Which of these performs better for SMALL collections?

```
if (! list.Contains (t)) list.Add (t);
```

Or

```
set.Add (t);
```

Source of doubt: [HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)

Comment: Why not get a try if it's important?

Comment: what's your definition of small?

Answer (score 4):

It really has to do with how you are going to use the data structures. If you need to access an item using an index, then you can't use a HashSet, also if you need to store duplicates, you can;t use HashSet. A List is typically used for most operations, so I you don't understand the underlying design and functionality of the HashSet, then chances are a List will suffice.[image]

Comment: According to MSDN List.Add() and HashSet.Add() both are O(1) if count is less than the capacity of the internal array and O(n) if the object needs to be resized.

Answer (score 1):

**HashSet** should be used in case when you care about the performance (especially if you know that you will operate on a large set of items) but do not care about the order.

Use **List** when you want to iterate through the collection. Iterating through all the items in a List it is generally much faster than through a set (unless you use inside such methods as Contains).

Check this sample for test the performance:

```
const int COUNT = 100000;
        HashSet<int> hashSetOfInts = new HashSet<int>();
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            hashSetOfInts.Add(i);
        }

        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            hashSetOfInts.Contains(i);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed);

        stopWatch.Reset();
        List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            listOfInts.Add(i);
        }

        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            listOfInts.Contains(i);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed);
        Console.Read();
```