# Lambda Expression using OR operator

Tags: c#, lambda

I believe there is a better way to write this but I am experiencing a mental block.

```
int num = 0;

using(var db = new TestDB())
{
    num = db.Table.Where(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" &&
                             (x.FavoriteColor == "Green" || 
                              x.FavoriteColor == "Blue" || 
                              x.FavoriteColor == "Red")).Count();
}

return num;
```

Is there a better way to write the `OR` statements? I have tried:

```
x.FavoriteColor == "Green" || "Blue" || "Red"
```

but the compiler says `Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Go for readability. I believe your current example is both readable and maintainable. It's nothing wrong with that. Do note if there is nothing between the `using` and the `return` statement you can just do `return db.Table.Where...`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick comments and answers. I didn't expect all of those answers to happen so rapidly haha but I guess that's why SO is #1.  @Default Thanks for note. I will be sure to use that. Thanks again

Comment: @Servy good point, I missed that. Removed the comment to avoid confusion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) method of array/list/hashset.

```
var colors = new List<string> {"Green", "Red", "Blue" };

db.Table.Where(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" &&
                         (colors.Contains (x.FavoriteColor)).Count()
```

It will generate SQL query like

```
SELECT ... WHERE FavoriteColor = 'Baseball' AND FavoriteColor in ("Green", "Red", "Blue")
```

I'd like to add that if you work with datasets which are stored in a memory you should bear in mind that List's `Contains` takes O(N) iteration to get result. So if `colors` contains a lot of elements you should use set [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) instead with O(1).

```
var colors = new HashSet<string> {"Green", "Red", "Blue", .... };

someDataSet.Where(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" &&
                         (colors.Contains (x.FavoriteColor)).Count()
```

You can find List-HashSet performance comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)

Comment: Always show the best example first IMO. You don't need to edit to the end of your answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a hashset have a performance boost? This is a query to the database, which is translated to dynamic SQL so it should iterate through the entire collection anyway.

Comment: @Valentin Ok, I agree in memory, a search through a hashset is more efficient (at times). The point I'm making is that this command should generate SQL (i.e., OP is using EF). The query generated should be "SELECT ... WHERE FavoriteSport = "Baseball" AND FavoriteColor IN (
Red", "Blue", "Green"). It would have to iterate  through the entire collection to generate the IN statement.

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk Yes, thanks.As I consider both of the cases build same sql query with the same performance.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] FavColor = new string[]{"Green","Red","Blue"};

int num = 0;

    using(var db = new TestDB())
    {
        num = db.Table.Where(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" &&FavColor.Any(x.FavoriteSport)).Count();
    }

    return num;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a container of objects and use the Contains method. For example:

```
var favoriteColors = new List<string>
{
   "Blue", "Green", "Red"
};
var num = 0;

using(var db = new TestDB())
{
  num = db.Table.Where(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" && favoriteColors.Contains(x.FavoriteColor)).Count();
}
```

I would check a profile to make sure that the generated SQL is using teh IN statement though.

Answer (score 3):

pretty much what everyone has said - you can make a collection of valid strings and see if your string is in that collection.  You can do it inline:

```
num = db.Table.Count(x => x.FavoriteSport == "Baseball" &&
                       new []{"Green","Red","Blue"}.Contains(x.FavoriteColor);
```

Worth noting that you can swap your `Where` out for `Count` directly