# How to load file fully and process record csvreader?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use the CSV reader and found that it takes a lot of time to parse the data. how can I load the entire csv file to memory and then process it record by record as I have to do custom mapping of the records.

```
  TextReader tr = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\MarketData\" + symbol + ".txt", FileMode.Open));
  CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(tr);
  while (csvr.Read())
{
// do your magic
}
```

Comment: Well .NET streams already uses buffering so are you sure that's the problem?   How large is the file?  You may want to try the **async** methods

Comment: its about 10 MB per file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: You can load the file fully into a memory stream and then re-read from that stream using your CsvReader. Similarly, you can create a bigger read buffer for your filestream, eg, 15MB, which would read the entire file into the buffer in one hit. I doubt either of these will actually improve performance for 10MB files.

Find your real performance bottleneck: Time to read file content from disk, time to parse CSV into fields, or time to process a record? A 10MB file looks really small. I'm processing sets of 250MB+ csv files with a custom csv reader with no complaints.

If processing is the bottleneck and you have several threads available and your csv file format does not need to support escaped line breaks, then you could read the entire file into a list of lines (System.IO.File.ReadAllLines / .ReadLines) and parse each line using a different Task. For example:

```
System.IO.File.ReadLines()
.Skip(1)                  // header line. Assume trusted to be correct.
.AsParallel()
.Select(ParseRecord)      // RecordClass ParseRecord(string line)
.ForAll(ProcessRecord);   // void ProcessRecord(RecordClass)
```

If you have many files to parse, you could process each file in a different Task and use async methods to maximise throughput. If they all come from the same physical disk then your milage will vary and may even get worse than a single-threaded approach.

More advanced:

If you know your files to contain 8-bit characters only, then you can operate on byte arrays and skip the StreamReader overheads to cast bytes into chars. This way you can read the entire file into a byte array in a single call and scan for line breaks assuming no line break escapes need to be supported. In that case scanning for line breaks can be done by multiple threads, each looking at a part of the byte array.

If you don't need to support field escapes (a,"b,c",d), then you can write a faster parser, simply looking for field separators (typically comma). You can also split field-demarcation parsing and field content parsing into threads if that's a bottleneck, though memory access locality may negate any benefits.

Under certain circumstances you may not need to parse fields into intermediate data structures (eg doubles, strings) and can process directly off references to the start/end of fields and save yourself some intermediate data structure creation.

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that exactly represents/mirrors your CSV file. Then read all the contents into a list of that class. The following snip is from CsvHelper's documentation.

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
```

The important part is the .ToList(), as this will force the load of all the data into your list, rather than yielding results as you access them.

You can then perform additional mapping / extraction on that list, which will be in memory.

If you're already doing this, you may benefit from loading your csv into a HashSet rather than a List via (ToHashSet()). See [HashSet vs List Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)