# Display a single message with records when Id exists in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have to check record if exists then display a message with `Id` stating that following `Id's` exists.
As I have written the message in a loop so the message is repeated.
If I write the console message outside the loop then scope ends.

Current output :

> Cannot delete as Id 1 exists.
>   Cannot delete as Id 2 exists.

Required Output :

> Cannot delete as Id 1,2 exists.

```
public class Program
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Program> client = new List<Program>();

        client.Add(new Program { Id = 1 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 2 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 3 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 4 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 5 });


        List<Program> server = new List<Program>();
        server.Add(new Program { Id = 2});
        server.Add(new Program { Id = 4 });

        foreach (var c in client)
        {
            var r = server.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id);
            if (r==true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cannot delete as {0} exists",c.Id));    
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
public class Program
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Program> client = new List<Program>();

        client.Add(new Program { Id = 1 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 2 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 3 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 4 });
        client.Add(new Program { Id = 5 });


        List<Program> server = new List<Program>();
        server.Add(new Program { Id = 2});
        server.Add(new Program { Id = 4 });
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        foreach (var c in client)
        {
            var r = server.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id);
            if (r==true)
            {
                lst.Add(c.Id);

            }

        }

        if(lst.Count() > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cannot delete as {0} exists",string.Join(",",lst)));    

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a neat way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be perfect, but will work for you, so modify your code to

```
string allID = "";   
foreach (var c in client)
{
    var r = server.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id);

    if (r==true)
    {
        allID += c.Id + ","; //will append values of matched c.ID with a comma
    }
}

allID = allID.Remove(allID.Length - 1); //Removes the last extra comma
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cannot delete as {0} exists", allID));
```

Output:

> Cannot delete as Id 1,2 exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the string outside the loop and build it when you find new conflicting Ids. Also, check that there is at least 1 conflicting Id in the string before outputing an error message.

```
string existingIds = "";

foreach (var c in client)
{
    var r = server.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id);
    if (r == true)
    {
        if (existingIds.Equals(string.Empty))
            existingIds += c.Id;
        else
            existingIds += "," + c.Id;
    }
}

if (existingIds.Equals(string.Empty))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cannot delete as {0} exists", existingIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136) of two collections:

```
var intersect = client.Select(c => c.Id).Intersect(server.Select(s => s.Id));    // 2, 4

if (intersect.Any())
    Console.WriteLine($"Cannot delete as Id {string.Join(", ", intersect)} exists");
```

or a bit more efficient:

```
var server = new HashSet<int> { 2, 4 };
server.IntersectWith(client.Select(c => c.Id));

if (server.Count > 0)
    Console.WriteLine($"Cannot delete as Id {string.Join(", ", server)} exists");
```

Comment: would like to know why Hashset here, it's better than List in performance.

Comment: @Dave with `List` or `Array`, you have to compare each item in the list to check if it contains certain value. With hashed collections like `Dictionary` and `HashSet`, a hash number is calculated from the value to estimate where to look for it, and only few elements are compared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance