# How to find a specific element in a List

Tags: c#, list, linq, find, contains

I want to filter my `List` and if an `item` *already exists*, I don't want to add that `item` to that `List`. That's why I try to filter by the `item` property.

```
if(!(PolyLineList.Contains(PolyLineList.Find(x => x.item == item))))
{
    cPolyline currentPolyLine = new cPolyline(pointlist,item);
    PolyLineList.Add(currentPolyLine);
}
```

When an `item` *already exists* in `PolyLineList`, that is equal to `item`, it should *skip* the `if`-statement.

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method:

```
if (!PolyLineList.Any(x => x.item == item))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will slow down greatly as the list grows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762995/9945524

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Of course it will, that goes without saying. I did have an edit which suggested keeping a separate HashSet of the `item` property, but it was hard to articulate clearly without knowing much of the context (such as the type of the `item` property), given that the OP is obviously fairly inexperienced.

Comment: that's just what my answer is doing, unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti It is, yes. Although I think that could be unclear to the OP - you need to make it clear that items are removed from `itemSet` when they're removed from `PolyLineList`, and that `itemSet` and `PolyLineList` need to have the same storage duration, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change `List<T>` to `HashSet<T>` and just `Add` (providing that `PolyLine` implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for `PolyLine` instances to be compared):

```
 //TODO: you, probably, want to rename PolyLineList into PolyLineSet or something 
 HashSet<cPolyline> PolyLineList = new HashSet<cPolyline>();

 ...

 PolyLineList.Add(currentPolyLine);
```

Comment: Note that 1) this relies on the OP overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `cPolyline` to do equality based only on the `name` member, and 2) assumes that order in `PolyLineList` is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the type of `item` is `ItemType`:

```
var itemSet = new HashSet<ItemType>();
```

...

```
if (itemSet.Add(item))
{ // item is unique
    PolyLineList.Add(new cPolyline(pointlist,item));
}
```