# Fastest Type of Collection of indexed complex Ocjects

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, hashmap, delaunay

**I'm looking for the most elegant, fastest and most efficient way to store several objects of the class `Point` with an index/key in any kind of collection.**

`Point` contains attributes like `index`, `posX`, `posY`, `area`, `neighborPoints[]`, `AdjacentTriangles[]`, etc. and are used for creating a Delaunay-Triangulation and a Voronoi-Mesh.
For reasons of selection the single points should have an index in the collection, but don't need to be ordered.
While triangulating, I'm *creating* and *deleting* points. Also I want to *loop through* all points in the collection. Hence, the type of collection should be optimized for these operations.

In the beginning I used a `List<Point>` for storing the points and the occurence in the list was identical with the index of the point. In case of deleting one point of the list, I had to decrease all indices of the higher points. This sounds pretty inconvenient and time-consuming to me.

This is why I tried `Dictionary<int, Point>` afterwards. Here the indices are fixed and if I delete for example the second point, then all higher points, maybe `Point[5]` stays `Point[5]`, just `Point[1]` is not there anymore (return is `null`). However, my runtimes are now even longer (see picture), although I don't have to do the index-shifting anymore. (Why is this?)
[image: runtimes]

Using a `Hashmap` makes no sence to me, since then I would not be able to use calls like `Point.posX` (error code CS1061), because in a Hashmap the datatype is not set.

**Do you have any suggestion for a efficient type of collection with faster performance?**

Comment: Do you really need a dictionary to have Key access? This may help you: [HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance) and [HashSet vs List vs Dictionary. HashSet](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/),

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how a Dictionary of just 5000 points could take so long to process. Could you post a simple version of your code so we can diagnose what's going on?

Comment: @Slothario more or less its the Bowyer-Watson algorithm from the pseudocode in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm I have one collection for all points and one for all triangles

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the points along a hilbert curve. Basically the Bowyer-Watson algorithm use the hilbert curve.