# HashSet<T> to be sorted using a custom IComparer without using LINQ

Tags: c#, collections, interface, hashset, icomparer

**Scenario**

I have a custom class (called `FeedData`) that would collected in a `HashSet<FeedData>`

```
internal struct FeedData
{
    internal string ID;
    internal Vector2d Location;
}
```

I now have a custom `IComparer` that would help sort the `HashSet<FeedData>` from nearest to the farthest location to the user's location. The comparision happens with `FeedData.Location`

```
internal sealed class DistanceComparer : IComparer<FeedData>
{

    private CheapRuler cheapRuler;
    private Vector2d userLocation;

    //Constructor
    internal DistanceComparer(Vector2d _currentLocation)
    {
        this.userLocation = _currentLocation;
        this.cheapRuler = new Geo.CheapRuler(userLocation.x, Geo.CheapRulerUnits.Meters);
    }

    // Interface IComparer<FeedData> implementation
    int IComparer<FeedData>.Compare(FeedData _feedA, FeedData _feedB)
    {
        int _comparision = cheapRuler.Distance(_feedA.Location, userLocation)
                                .CompareTo(cheapRuler.Distance(_feedB.Location, userLocation));
        return _comparision;
    }

}
```

**Objective**

Without using `System.Linq` how can I sort a `HashSet<FeedData>`

*Reason for using HashSet* opposed to another collection (say List) is at any time the count of FeedData could be significantly higher that performance would be in check. 
[[HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance) ]

**Other Operations on HashSet**

- Insert/Add `FeedData`
- Removal of an item

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HashSet cannot be sorted. 
An alternative collection type is SortedSet, which can be instantiated by a comparator object that implements the ICompare interface.
Other possible alternative collection types are: SortedList, SortedDictionary

[SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8)