# Is there a type of unordered collection in .NET which can add and remove objects quickly?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

So I have a special class which can remove itself from a collection, let's say it looks something like this:

```
public class FunTimes{
    public ICollection<FunTimes> Collection {get;set;}
    protected void RemoveFromCollection(){
        Collection.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

`RemoveFromCollection()` will be called from an event. I want the collection to add and remove items quickly, and since position doesn't matter in my case, I planned to use something other than a `List<T>`. I can't really use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, since I have to iterate over every item to remove an item. I've finally decided to use a `Dictionary<FunTimes, FunTimes>`, and then use each `FunTimes` instance as both the key *AND* the value. I'm asking if there's a better solution because using an object as both the key and the value in a Dictionary just seems plain weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/selecting-a-collection-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Dictionary<FunTimes, FunTimes>` satisfies your needs better option would be using [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) which should have [O(1) addition and removal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949528/2501279).

Comment: Man I feel dumb, I'm not sure how I missed this, thanks!

Comment: @octillerysnacker was glad to help!