# How do I make an integer be added to a list, then get the sum of the list with a button?

Tags: c#, list, hashset

The subtotal should be equal to 9500, and not 9000. I have the code to add a price to a hashset list, but when I click the compute button it's only getting one integer instead of adding them all.

```
private void computeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double soloPrice = 0.00;
        string selling = Convert.ToString(applianceList.SelectedItem);
        HashSet<double> subTotalPrice = new HashSet<double>(15);
        foreach (string price in itemTag.Items)
        {
            if (selling == "Electric Fan" && !subTotalPrice.Contains(500.00))
            {
                subTotalPrice.Add(500.00 * Convert.ToDouble(itemsNumber.Value));
                soloPrice = 500.00 * Convert.ToDouble(itemsNumber.Value);
            }                   
            else if (selling == "Refrigerator" && !subTotalPrice.Contains(9000.00))
            {
                subTotalPrice.Add(9000.00 * Convert.ToDouble(itemsNumber.Value));
                soloPrice = 9000.00 * Convert.ToDouble(itemsNumber.Value);
            }
            itemPrice.Text = "₱" + soloPrice;
        subTotal.Text = "₱ " + subTotalPrice.Sum();
    }
```

[image: Program output]

Comment: If you have an complete HashSet with every integer in, you can use for loop to iterate over the set to access every element and do the summation

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand how you are intending for your program to work. You might want to post more code. Normally you would do something like `mySelectedItems.Sum(i => i.Price)`.

Comment: Unrelated: do not represent monetary amounts as floating point types.

Comment: You are using `else if` and condition on `selling`'s value, so only one branch will be hit. Always. Because `selling` can only have _one_ of the values.

Comment: ... [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Fildor It is _somewhat_ related, since `Contains` on a `HashSet` is going to do equality checks and equality checks on floating point are "problematic".

Comment: @mjwills Excellent point, but it wasn't the reasoning I based the comment on. But yes, considering this, it is indeed related.

Comment: Another point to consider: Do you really want to adjust your code anytime there is a new item type available?

Answer (score -2):

> ... get the sum of the list

In your question you talk about a `List<T>` and in your code you use `HashSet<T>` - which are different ways to store data and have different advantages. You can read more about them [Here at MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/718a76de-90c7-4d09-b8aa-4dcd8333e729/when-to-use-hashset-class-instead-of-list?forum=csharpgeneral) and [Here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)

I would go with a `List<T>` object since you can access it with indexing operator [].

First, I declared a HashSet with type being integer and initialized with 3 values.

```
HashSet<int> set = new() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Then at this code block I used an for loop to iterate over the HashSet and used ElementAt() method to access every element.

I gathered numbers one by one and added them to the `summation` variable so you can access it later on.

```
int summation = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < set.Count; i++)
{
    summation = summation + set.ElementAt(i);
}
return summation;
```

I would suggest you to read about List and use it rather than a HashSet.

Comment: code-only answers are generally frowned upon. please add some *explanation* as to how and why your solution works. please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is not really any different from just using `.Sum()`, I'm fairly confident the posters problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @JonasH using methods provided by LINQ is mostly much slower than going with a simple for loop, that's why I went with a longer method. But as mentioned by other commenters, the question is quite ambiguous

Comment: @fybalaban Sure, but the poster only seem to be adding a few items, and the question is how to get the correct result, not to get it faster.

Comment: @JonasH In fact, OP only ever adds 1 item because of how he put the conditions.