# Find all active/inactive gameObjects that has common script attached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find all active and nonactive gameObjects which have a common script added to them. I am able to find all active gameObjects but unfortunately the inactive ones do not get viewed by my script. How can I overcome this?

```
public myScript[] commonScripts;

void Start() {
 commonScripts = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(myScript)) as myScript[];
}
```

Comment: What about simply using [`FindObjectsOfType<myScript>(true)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) ... ?

Comment: Thank you so much that actually worked!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a different approach where the component instance adds itself to a list in `Awake` or `Start`

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
         FindObjectOfType<ContainerClass>().Add(this);
    }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
         FindObjectOfType<ContainerClass>().Remove(this);
    }
}

public class ContainerClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<MyScript> scripts = new List<MyScript>();
    
    public void Add(MyScript script)
    {
         scripts.Add(script);
    }
    public void Remove(MyScript script)
    {
         scripts.Remove(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this `FindObjectOfType<ContainerClass>().Add(this);` supposed to compile ... you get a `ContainerClass[]` then try to use `Add` on it and add a `MyScript` instance ... doesn't make any sense at all ^^

Comment: It's FindObjectOfType not FindObjectsOfType so you get a single item.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad now I see what you mean! Still: Why have a dedicated component for that and not just do it in the class itself?

Comment: I understand the original example implies it would be a separate component. And doing it in the class would mean you have many iteration of the same action. Else it would mean static which is the other answer.

Comment: ContainerClass can also be passed around with the consideration it may be persistent while those MyScript objects may well be destroyed. All in all, description is a bit left to the imagination.

Comment: In my eyes it would be way better to use `static` than rely on that an instance of another class hopefully is somewhere active in the scene ;) ... either way there now is also [`FindObjectsOfType<T>(bool)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and this and the other solution(s) are already in the duplicate link ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `myScript` is one of your C# scripts, I'd use a `static list` containing all instances.

#### Sample Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<MyScript> allObjects = new List<MyScript>();

    private void Start()
    {
        if (allObjects.Contains(this) == false)
            allObjects.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (allObjects.Contains(this))
            allObjects.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

#### You can use this in any other class as follows

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AnotherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void AnyFunction()
    {
        foreach (MyScript ms in MyScript.allObjects)
        {
            // do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider to rather use a `HashSet` .. depending on the amount of instances

Comment: Definitely. But it still depends on the use case.

Comment: not really .. the use case is clear ;) It rather depends on the amount of elements whether `Contains` and `Add` are [more performant on a `List` or a `HashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance) ;)