# ways to improve the time of the execution - Data structures

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I am learning Data Structures and I am stuck in a problem I cannot find the way to improve the performance of the code. The problem is this: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contacts/problem I made the solution and I could pass 3 of the 15 tests, but the rest I couldn´t because show me:

> Time limit exceeded Your code did not execute within the time limits.
> Please optimize your code. For more information on execution time
> limits, refer to the environment page

I change the nested if with linq, but I couldn't get the improvement. Could you help me? I left the code I am using:

```
public static List<int> contacts (List<List<string>> queries)
{
    List<string> contactList = new List<string>();
    List<string> findList = new List<string>();
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    foreach (var instruction in queries)
    {
        if (instruction[0] == "add") 
            contactList.Add(instruction[1]);
        else
            findList.Add(instruction[1]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < findList.Count; i++)
    {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        var counter = contactList.Where(x => x.Contains(findList[i])).Count();
        result.Add(counter);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //foreach (var contact in contactList)
        //{
        //    if (contact.Contains(findList[i]))
        //        result[i]++;
        //}
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance

Comment: it should be x.Startswith - which will for sure be faster. Store them in order in a SortedSet, then iterate youself and stop once the first letter you see is not the first letter of the search string

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices! I made a research about the issue and I leave the solution in C#

> ```
> using System.Collections.Generic;
>
> namespace ConsoleApp2 {
> internal class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         var x = contacts(new List<List<string>>() {
>             new List<string> {"add", "hack" },
>             new List<string> {"add", "hackerrank" },
>             new List<string> {"find", "hac" },
>             new List<string> {"find", "hak" }
>         });
>     }
>
>     public static List<int> contacts (List<List<string>> queries)
>     {
>         Trie trie = new Trie();
>         var findList = new List<int>();
>         foreach (var instruction in queries)
>         {
>             if (instruction[0] == "add") 
>                 trie.add(instruction[1]);
>             else
>                 findList.Add(trie.find(instruction[1]));
>         }
>         return findList;
>     }
> }
> class TrieNode
> {
>     private Dictionary<char, TrieNode> children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
>     public int size;
>
>     public void putChildIfAbsent(char ch)
>     {
>         if(!children.ContainsKey(ch))
>             children.Add(ch, new TrieNode());
>     }
>
>     public TrieNode getChild(char ch)
>     {
>         if (children.ContainsKey(ch))
>             return children[ch];
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> class Trie
> {
>     TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
>
>     public void add(string str)
>     {
>         TrieNode curr = root;
>         foreach(char ch in str)
>         {
>             curr.putChildIfAbsent(ch);
>             curr=curr.getChild(ch);
>             curr.size++;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public int find(string prefix)
>     {
>         TrieNode curr = root;
>
>         foreach(char ch in prefix)
>         {
>             curr= curr.getChild(ch);
>             if (curr == null)
>                 return 0;
>         }
>         return curr.size;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }