Unique ID generation without using GUID
I was trying to think of a way to get unique IDs without using GUID and thought of this.  Just wondering what you all think, if it's safe or not, etc.
    // IDGEN:  an auto incrementing ID for our nodes
    public int IDGen;
    public List<int> IDs;

    // NEWID:   will generate a unique ID for a node.  Whenever a node is destroyed 
    //          its ID will be put back in the IDs list and reused to ensure we never go over limit
    public int NewID()
    {
        if (IDs.Count > 0) { int i = IDs[0]; IDs.RemoveAt(0); return i; }
        else { return _.game.IDGen += 1; }
    }


Why bother with the list - are you expecting more than 2 billion uses in a session? GUIDs are mostly used when the values need to survive the session or will be shared among processes - your proposed solution suggests that's not the case here.

Linked lists are expensive. They can be good on a benchmark but in real-wold application, node are likely spread in memory and the addresses are located everywhere in memory so they are unpredictable for the CPU. This is a problem since it is likely to cause cache misses. The resulting latency is likely the one of a DRAM access (dozens of ns and hundreds of cycles). I am pretty confident there is a faster way to generate GUID than that. A growing-array (with a power-of-two growth policy) should be better, or even a List of buckets.

A better data structure could be to pack bits in 64-bit integers in a hierarchical data structure. When an integer has all its bit set then you compress its representation by setting a bit in another 64-bit integer (enabling 4096 items to be packed in a 64 bit integer). In the worst case bits are randomly set and you need 1 bit per GUID as opposed to something like 100x more currently. This strongly reduce the memory required in pathological cases while avoiding cache misses. Bit-packing can be done in less than 10 ns on most platforms (possibly significantly less, like on x86 CPUs).

TL;DR: on modern CPUs, computation is cheap while (unpredictable) memory accesses are expensive.

@500-InternalServerError - ya I am saving the IDs.  There will be between 5 - 10 million different IDs required but overtime I want a way to reuse them.  So if a node gets deleted then I add its ID to the list and it will be reused instead of incrementing the IDGen.

@JérômeRichard - The bit packing is pretty interesting.  I might try it out in the future.  I'm saving millions of the IDs so I wanted to reduce space from 128bit GUID and also it's just easier to work with int instead.

By the way, IDK if this is a problem but not NewID is not thread safe. Besides, an aggressive optimization is simply to just always add 1 if the considered part of the GUID is sufficiently large. For 128-bit integers, you can safely do that. In fact, it is also safe for 64-bit too. Regarding 64-bit integers, an overclocked CPU running at 10 GHz (hard to do more even in 10 years) hammering the GUI function will take several decades (~60 years for 64-bit unsigned integers) to overflow assuming each calls take 1 cycle ;) .

@JérômeRichard - oh lol, I was wondering how long it would take to do that

What exactly is your use case? for most things probably a simple HashSet would be enough .. has comparably fast way to check if an ID is already contained depending on how many items you expect .. see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance if you are concerned about amount of IDs you can still go for uint or ulong where required ..

@derHugo - its for a video game.  The list is not going to be big at all, maybe max size 100 at any given time so I don't think it would be heavy on performance.  It's just a matter of deleting nodes over time and reusing their IDs.

If you only need about 100 items go for byte instead ;) .. still it doesn't really tell us anything about the use case though .. how often will new IDs be required? How often reused?

You may prefer using Queue over List. And whether it's safe or not depends on your use case. For example, Unity DOTS Entities system is reusing IDs for entities and nothing bad happens.

@derHugo - There will be a couple of million different IDs that are going to be saved.  But as the player deletes/create nodes over time I want an auto incrementing ID but I don't want it to go over the limit over time so when nodes are deleted I add them to that list for them to be reused.  If there are no reusable IDs then it auto increments.  There will only ever be a couple of million at any given time.

You said 100 items before .. so how exactly are those IDs used? Do you need them within one session or beyond sessions (you are speaking of "saved" now)?

@derHugo - they are being set to "nodes" on a map that are saved via binary.  The 100 is just the amount the reusable ID list will ever rise to.  The nodes will reach millions but the list will only ever be a couple hundred as the player deletes large sections of nodes and creates more, etc etc, over time.
