# When do I need to escape characters within a regex character set (within [])?

Tags: javascript, regex

Are the rules for what I escape in a bracket different for what I do outside of brackets?

For example should I escape a `?` inside a bracket? Is it `/blah[^?]/` or `/blah[^\?]/`

Are the rules for brackets different than not, or should I be escaping both the same?

Comment: the title don't match with the real question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be escaped in brackets is a closing bracket, and a minus if it is not initial or final, and a hat if it is initial, AFAIK. And the backslash itself, obviously.

The reason is, these are the only characters with a special significance inside the brackets. A closing bracket ends the brackets, a mid-string minus indicates a range, and an initial hat negates the bracket class. Everything else should be literally interpreted. The backslash is the escape character, so you need a double backslash to match a literal backslash.

Comment: +1 for this and for the term "hat". Does that mean that I shouldn't escape it?

Comment: @qwertymk Only if it isn't the first character, and you don't want the hat to mean "not".

Comment: @qwertymk: Look at it this way: `[^a]` matches non-`a`. `[a^]` matches `a` or `^`. `[\^a]` matches the same, `a` or `^`. (Oh, and I forgot the backslash itself! EDIT!) `[\\^a]` matches `\`, `a` or `^`.

Comment: @Amadan: So it's not recommended to escape anything other than what's needed?

Comment: @qwertymk: AFAICT, for non-alphanumerics, it won't hurt anything but readability. Alphanumerics have a distinct meaning when escaped (e.g. `[\d]` is synonymous with `\d` and `[0-9]`).

Comment: A (forward) slash needs to be escaped, too.

Comment: @dev-null: Trueish. A forward slash needs to be escaped in a regexp _literal_ (both within brackets and not), and does not need escaping when passed to regexp _constructor_ (both within brackets and not): `/\/[\/]/`, but `new RegExp("/[/]")` is fine.

Comment: Python >= 3.7 emits a future warning if a character set contains an unescaped opening square bracket. https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#re

Comment: @wedi The question is tagged [tag:javascript] though.

Comment: Oh. Tags. You are right. I'll still leave my comment for any fellow python people stumbling upon this question.