# Extract number from string with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to extract number from string like

```
<p id="example">etc etc(5)</p>
<p id="example2">etc etc(-5)</p>
```

I'm using this code

```
alert($("#example").text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]);
```

It's work fine if the number is positive but in the case of a negative number 
get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

please help me about that 
thank's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.match(/\((-?\d+)\)/)[1]
```

`-?` says "optional minus".

Comment: `\-?` would probably be a safer habit to develop, as the hyphen is a reserved char which is used to specify character ranges inside []

Comment: @Cheekysoft: I was just [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10593427/240443) that question today. The grammar inside `[]` is very different than outside; I see no reason to pollute one with artifacts of the other.

Comment: meh, just a question of taste really. I like it when rules can be boiled down to the simpler set, especially when teaching. Personally i find it better to get into the practice of knowing the reserved characters and always quoting them, as it is completely safe to do so. The fact that it is unnecessary doesn't interest me. It's easier to follow the same methodology even if it is strictly "not required". ...But i'm not here to continue a religious war :-) I have at least as much respect for your POV as my own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
alert($("#example").text().match(/\((-?\d+)\)/)[1]);​
```

That will capture negative numbers as well.