# Making sure a file name is valid before creation

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I'm programmatically writing to a file like this:

```
file = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test\\sub\\" + post.title + ".txt");
file.Write(postString);
file.Close();
```

However, sometimes the program crashes because illegal characters for a file name are in `post.title`. Characters like `<` and `"`.

How can I transform `post.title` into a safe filename?

Comment: Unless you're doing some internal development for within your company, you should rather user `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` instead of the hard-coded path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general approach is to scrub the `post.title` value for characters in `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx

This similar thread shows approaches on how to do string replacements for sanitation purposes:
[C# Sanitize File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309485/c-sharp-sanitize-file-name)

In case that link goes down, here's a pretty good answer from the thread:

```
private static string MakeValidFileName( string name )
{
   string invalidChars = Regex.Escape( new string( Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() ) );
   string invalidReStr = string.Format( @"[{0}]+", invalidChars );
   return Regex.Replace( name, invalidReStr, "_" );
}
```

Comment: A good answer, just keep in mind the caveat: "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names." - you may need to tailor per filesystem type.

Answer (score 0):

If it's crashing due to an exception on the StreamWriter constructor (as seems likely), you can simply place that within an exception catching block.

That way, you can make your code *handle* the situation rather than just falling in a heap.

In other words, something like:

```
try {
    file = new StreamWriter ("C:\\Users\\me\\sub\\" + post.title + ".txt");
catch (Exception e) {  // Should also probably be a more fine-grained exception
    // Do something intelligent, notify user, loop back again 
}
```

In terms of morphing a filename to make it acceptable, the list of allowable characters in a large number of file systems was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename/4814088#4814088).

Basically, the second table in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) (`Comparison of filename limitations`) shows what is and isn't allowed.

You could use regex replacement to ensure that all the invalid characters are turned into something valid, such as `_`, or removed altogether.