# Handling null in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, null

I am new to linq, and this keeps popping on a null volume field. The file is unpredictable, and it will happen so I would like to put a 0 in where there is an exception. any quick and easy way to do it?

```
     var qry =
            from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\T.txt")
            let myRecX = line.Split(',')
            select new myRec()

            {

               price =   Convert.ToDecimal( myRecX[0].Replace("price =  ", "")) ,
               volume = Convert.ToInt32(myRecX[1].Replace("volume =", "")),
                dTime = Convert.ToDateTime( myRecX[2].Replace("timestamp =", ""))

            };
```

Comment: i would consider using a regular expression instead.

Comment: Are you getting a null reference exception or an array index out of bounds exception?

Comment: *"I would like to put a 0 in where there is an exception"* -- this seems like a bad idea? Why would you prefer *corrupt data* over an error?

Comment: @DanielA.White *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."* ;)

Comment: 0 is required if the data line exsists. The system it comes out of I have no control over. zero length string is the error

Comment: You would probably be better off using a dedicated file parsing library such as [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) which will be provide a more robust, flexible and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to use a default when the incoming data is `null`, empty, or consists entirely of whitespace characters, you can do it like this:

```
volume = string.IsNullOrWhitesplace(myRecX[1])
       ? defaultVolume // <<== You can use any constant here
       : Convert.ToInt32(myRecX[1].Replace("volume =", ""))
```

However, this is a "quick and dirty" way of achieving what you need, because the position of each named parameter remains hardcoded. A more robust way would be writing a mini-parser that pays attention to the names of attributes specified in the file, rather than replacing them with an empty string.

Comment: Beautiful, I had to add the replace functionality to both comparisons, but worked like a charm volume = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myRecX[1].Replace("volume =", ""))
                        ? 0 // <<== You can use any constant here
                        : Convert.ToInt32(myRecX[1].Replace("volume =", "")),

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, which offers an expressive way to write what you want:

```
static TOutput Convert<TInput, TOutput>(
    TInput value,
    params Func<TInput, TOutput>[] options)
{
    foreach (var option in options) {
        try { return option(value); }
        catch { }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("No option succeeded.");
}
```

Used like:

```
select new myRec()
{
   price = Convert(myRecX[0].Replace("price =  ", ""),
                   input => Convert.ToDecimal(input),
                   or => 0M),
   ...
};
```

The function indirection and implicit array construction may incur a slight performance penalty, but it gives you a nice syntax with which to specify a number of possible conversions, where the first successful one is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think here there's an issue beyond the use of `Linq`.

In general is bad practice manipulating file data before sanitizing it.

Ever if the following question is on the filename  (rather than it's content) is a good starting point to understand the concept of *sanitizing input*:

[C# Sanitize File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309485/c-sharp-sanitize-file-name)

After all yourself tells that your code lacks control of the file content, so before call:

`let myRecX = line.Split(',')`

I suggest define a private method like:

```
string SanitizeInputLine(string input) {
  // here do whatever is needed to bring back input to 
  // a valid format in a way that subsequent calls will not
  // fail

  return input;
}
```

Applying it is straightforward;

`let myRecX = SanitizeInputLine(line).Split(',')`

**As general rule never trust input.**

Let me quote Chapter 10 named _All Input Is Evil!__  of [Writing Secure Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228) by Howard/LeBlanc:

> ...you should never trust data until data is validated. Failure to do
>   so will render your application vulnerable. Or, put another way: *all
>   input is evil until proven otherwise*.