# CSV Character missing

Tags: c#, csv, umbraco

I have a code for download datatable values as csv format.It is working correctly and I can download the Csv.But the problem is my datatable contain some danish characters when i download the csv,the csv file contain all the details but the danish character is replaced with some other charactes. here is my code.

```
string myXMLfile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfilecsv.xml");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream(myXMLfile,
                                                          System.IO.FileMode.Open);

try
{
    ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];


    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                        Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", item.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
        }
        sb = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append("\n");

    }

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=mycsvfile.csv";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/csv";

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    umbraco.BusinessLogic.Log.Add(umbraco.BusinessLogic.LogTypes.Error, 00002, ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    fsReadXml.Close();
}
```

Can any one give a solution???

Comment: see my answer to another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577213/handling-null-in-linq/15577711#15577711); you should sanitize data before handling it

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is because absent encoding. Choose encoding (utf-8?) and append appropriate information to response for client.

Take a look at [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly) - you'll see some additional response headers and even a 'hack' specially for Excel.

Comment: Linked question says: (1) Additional 'Content-Encoding' header
(2) charset=UTF-8 to existing 'Content-Type' header (3) Byte-order-mark as first bytes of response data. I think you need check all 3 points.