# DateTime Not working in Global.asax in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to use DateTime in global.asax to give a name to a file but it gives an error. Could you please assist?

The code I am using for the DateTime;

```
public void callFileCreate()
{
    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileFolder"].ToString();


    string filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path + "\\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", ".") + "_" + (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Replace(":", "_") + ".txt");
    TraceFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path + "\\Scheduler" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", ".") + "_" + (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Replace(":", "_") + ".txt");
    FileStream fs = null, fs1 = null;
    fs = File.Create(filename);
    fs1 = File.Create(TraceFilePath);
    ErrorFilePath = filename;
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: did u forgot to use path from root i.e. `~/yourpath` in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileFolder"]`?

Comment: Most likely there were some characters that are not valid in file name. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/309485/447356) a way how to sanitize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Path` class if you work with paths:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileFolder"].ToString();
string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.txt"
    , "Log"
    , DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")  // change according to your actual culture
    , DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss"));
string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
```

Not sure if that solves your issue, but it increases readability and avoids careless mistakes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write what error you get. But here are some hints about how you can simplify your code:

```
var dir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileFolder"].ToString());
var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd_HH.mm.ss");

var logFilePath = Path.Combine(dir, string.Format("Log_{0}.txt", dt));
var traceFilePath = Path.Combine(dir, string.Format("Scheduler_{0}.txt", dt));

var fs = File.Create(logFilePath);
var fs1 = File.Create(traceFilePath);
```

Notes:

- if the app-settings entry *LogFileFolder* already contains an (absolute) filesystem-path such as `c:\temp`, then you shouldn't call `Server.MapPath()`.
- you should call `fs.Close()` once you no longer need the streams (or put it in a `using` block). Otherwise, another attempt to create the (same) file will result in an exception.

Comment: You don't know OP's culture, so you don't know if it is `yyyy.MM.dd` or `dd.MM.yyyy` or whatelse.

Comment: @Tim: I guess you want to have a consistent (i.e. culture-independent) format for the file names and not depend on the current culture (which might be different for each request/user in a web app).

Comment: Yes, but OP's original code was culture dependent, not sure if that's desired.