# regex - Replace all dots,special characters except for the file extension

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regex in such  a way that to replace the filename which contains special characters and dots(.) etc. with underscore(_) except the extension of the filename.

Help me with an regex

Comment: The Regex: ([!@#$%^&*()]|(?:[.](?![a-z0-9]+$))) is not processing if the extensions are in UpperCase....say for word documents DOC,TXT,HTML,XML,PDF,GIF,JPEG etc

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
([!@#$%^&*()]|(?:[.](?![a-z0-9]+$)))
```

with the insensitive flag "i". Replace with '_'

The first lot of characters can be customised, or maybe use \W (any non-word)

so this reads as:

replace with '_' where I match and of this set, or a period that is not followed by some characters or numbers and the end of line

Sample c# code:

```
var newstr = new Regex("([!@#$%^&*()]|(?:[.](?![a-z0-9]+$)))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Replace(myPath, "_");
```

Comment: added c# code - originally didn't realise it was a c# question

Comment: The Regex: ([!@#$%^&*()]|(?:[.](?![a-z0-9]+$))) is not processing if the extensions are in UpperCase....say for word documents DOC,TXT,HTML,XML,PDF,GIF,JPEG etc.

Comment: uh... yes it is. I mention twice, once on the third line, and once in the example code, to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

Since you only care about the extension, forget about the rest of the filename.  Write a regex to scrape off the extension, discarding the original filename, and then glue that extension onto the new filename.

This regular expression will match the extension, including the dot.: `\.[^.]*$`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just take off the extension first and put it back on after? Something like (but add your own list of special characters):

```
static readonly Regex removeChars = new Regex("[-. ]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static void Main() {
    string path = "ab c.-def.ghi";
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    path = Path.ChangeExtension(
        removeChars.Replace(Path.ChangeExtension(path, null), "_"), ext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you separate the file extension out from your string would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-trim-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames) then get you the rest of the way?