# Removing any element other than numbers from character array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a multi line string text that has in each line a phone number joined by some text or spacial characters(characters not in English) so I want to check the text line by line and for each line extract the phone number and keep it in a rich text box I faced one problem and that is how to Remove any element other than numbers from character array .. any help !!

```
using(StringReader reader=new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text))
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                do
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        // Checking if the line contains things other than letters
                        char[] buffer = line.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToCharArray();
                        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (!char.IsNumber(buffer[i]))
                            {
                                // Delete any letters or spacial characters
                            }
                        }

                        Regex rx = new Regex("^[730-9]{9}$");
                        if (rx.IsMatch(line))
                        {
                            richTextBox2.Text+=line;
                        }

                    }
                } while (line != null);

            }}
```

Comment: Don't use a character array. Iterate through the string. Neither a string nor an array allows removal of elements, so build a *new* string instead. Start with an empty string variable, and add to it each character that you wish to keep.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3210462/2457029) is what you are looking for

Comment: @EdPlunkett can you give me an example

Comment: @MohammedShfq Who wrote this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Char.IsDigit` should help:

```
string lineWithoutNumbers = line.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x));
```

In your case, something like this:

```
using(StringReader reader=new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    // Checking if the line contains things other than letters
                    line = new String(line.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray()); //here, we remove all non-digits from the line variable

                    Regex rx = new Regex("^[730-9]{9}$");
                    if (rx.IsMatch(line))
                    {
                        richTextBox2.Text+=line;
                    }

                }
            } while (line != null);

        }}
```

Comment: I want to keep the numbers

Comment: Might need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654190/ienumerablechar-to-string

Comment: @MohammedShfq so, you will, it returns only numbers

Comment: @MohammedShfq try now.