# Extract substring between startsequence and endsequence in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, extract

I have an XML instance that contains processing instructions. I want a specific one (the schematron declaration):

```xml
<?xml-model href="../../a/b/c.sch" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
```

There may or may not be more than these very processing instructions present, so I can't rely on its position in the DOM; it is guaranteed, on the other hand, that there will be only one (or none) such Schematron file reference. Thus, I get it like so:

```cs
XProcessingInstruction p = d.Nodes().OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
   .Where(x => x.Target.Equals("xml-model") && 
    x.Data.Contains("schematypens=\"http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron\""))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

In the example given, the content of `p.Data` is the string

```
href="../../a/b/c.sch" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
```

I **need to extract the path specified via @href** (i. e. in this example I would want the string `../../a/b/c.sch`) **without double quotes**. In other words: I need the substring after `href="` and before the next `"`. I'm trying to achieve my goal with LINQ:

```cs
var a = p.Data.Split(' ').Where(s => s.StartsWith("href=\""))
       .Select(s => s.Substring("href=\"".Length))
       .Select(s => s.TakeWhile(c => c != '"'));
```

I would have thought this gave me a `IEnumerable<char>` which I could then convert to a string in one of the ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654190/ienumerablechar-to-string), but that's not the case: According to LINQPad, I seem to be getting a `IEnumerabale<IEnumerable<char>>` which I can't manage to make into a string.

How could this be done correctly using LINQ? Maybe I'd better be using Regex within LINQ?

---

*Edit:* After typing this down, I came up with a working solution, but it seems very inelegant:

```cs
string a = new string
   (
      p.Data.Substring(p.Data.IndexOf("href=\"") + "href=\"".Length)
      .TakeWhile(c => c != '"').ToArray()
   );
```

What would be a better way?

Comment: *I would have thought this gave me a IEnumerable<char>* - it would if there were only one of them, but Where emits multiple strings, and the ultimate Select turns them into multiple character enumerations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = @"<?xml-model href=""../../a/b/c.sch"" schematypens=""http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron""?>";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"href=""(.*?)""");
var url = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

That gives me `../../a/b/c.sch` in `url`.

Please don't use Regex for general XML parsing, but for this situation it's fine.

Comment: I somehow thought - as I was using LINQ anyway - there should be an "entirely LINQ"-way for no reason; yours is by far more readable and simple. Thank you. And yes, I, too, would never process XML with regex, I'd either use LINQ while in C# or, preferably, simply XSLT/XQuery if possible).