# Howto allow “Illegal characters in path”? IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I've seen [.Net: How do I check for illegal characters in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435894/net-how-do-i-check-for-illegal-characters-in-a-path) but that is a slightly different situation. The solution for that person gives me configuration errors

I have a URL which is being intercepted by IIS because of a semi-colon and throwing a 404 page. I want to inside of my application capture that address and redirect it based on the contents of the url.

adding relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping or requestPathInvalidCharacters to the httpRuntime value in my webconfig results in a configuration error for the application: Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Is there an alternative way for websites that aren't .Net 4 to allow specific characters to pass through IIS checking?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the error in global.asax in application_error() event? You can get the last exception by using the Server.GetLastError().