# Recursively looping through a drive and replacing illegal characters

Tags: c#, recursion, replace

I have to create an app that drills into a specific drive, reads all file names and replaces illegal SharePoint characters with underscores.
The illegal characters I am referring to are:  `~ # % & * {} / \ | : <> ? - ""`

Can someone provide either a link to code or code itself on how to do this?  I am VERY new to C# and need all the help i can possibly get.  I have researched code on recursively drilling through a drive but i am not sure how to put the character replace and the recursive looping together.  Please help!

Comment: [1] When you say "replaces" do you mean, renames the files? [2] If you have code that will simply list all the files, you're almost there: edit your question and add the code. Then it will be easy to show you what to do.

Comment: I have created a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015965/changing-filenames-using-regex-and-recursion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advice for removing illegal characters is here:

[How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames/146162#146162)

You just have to change the character set to your set of characters that you want to remove.

If you have figured out how to recurse the folders, you can get all of the files in each folder with:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(currentPath);
```

and then

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    System.IO.File.Move(file, ConvertFileName(file));
}
```

The ConvertFileName method you will write to accept a filename as a string, and return a filename stripped of the bad characters.

Note that, if you are using .NET 3.5, `GetFiles()` works too.  According to MSDN:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles
>   methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start
>   enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is
>   returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names
>   to be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be
>   more efficient.

---

**How to recursively list directories**

```
string path = @"c:\dev";
string searchPattern = "*.*";

string[] dirNameArray = Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// Or, for better performance:
// (but breaks if you don't have access to a sub directory; see 2nd link below)
IEnumerable<string> dirNameEnumeration = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

- [How to: Enumerate Directories and Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx)
- [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c/929418#929418)

Comment: Use SPUrlUtility.IsLegalCharInUrl(char character) to determine an illegal "SharePoint" file char.

Comment: @Jared: Those Enumerate* methods are new, I think in .NET 4.  As you can imagine, they return IEnumerable instead of some sort of list.

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, but consider both of the following:

The following characters are not valid in filenames anyways so you don't have to worry about them: `/\:*?"<>|`.

Make sure your algorithm handles duplicate names appropriately.  For example, `My~Project.doc` and `My#Project.doc` would both be renamed to `My_Project.doc`.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive method to rename files in folders is what you want. Just pass it the root folder and it will call itself for all subfolders found.

```
private void SharePointSanitize(string _folder)
{
    // Process files in the directory
    string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(_folder);
    foreach(string fileName in files)
    {
        File.Move(fileName, SharePointRename(fileName));
    }
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(_folder);
    foreach(string folderName in folders)
    {
        SharePointSanitize(folderName);
    }
}

private string SharePointRename(string _name)
{
    string newName = _name;
    newName = newName.Replace('~', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('#', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('%', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('&', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('*', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('{', '');
    newName = newName.Replace('}', '');
    // .. and so on
    return newName;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. You can replace the `''` in the `SharePointRename()` method to whatever character you want to replace with, such as an underscore.
2. This does not check if two files have similar names like thing~ and thing%

Comment: Props to Steven (+1) for noting the duplicate file issue in my note #2

Comment: Or create an array: `char[] invalidList = new char[] { '~', '#', ... }` and use a loop to replace: `foreach (char invalid in invalidList) { newName = newName.Replace(invalid, '_'); }`  However, this has to create a new string every time since it's immutable.  Maybe a regex would be faster because of that reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex _pattern = new Regex("[~#%&*{}/\\|:<>?\"-]+");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
        RecursivelyRenameFilesIn(di);
    }

    public static void RecursivelyRenameFilesIn(DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fi in root.GetFiles())
            if (_pattern.IsMatch(fi.Name))
                fi.MoveTo(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", fi.Directory.FullName, Regex.Replace(fi.Name, _pattern.ToString(), "_")));

        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in root.GetDirectories())
            RecursivelyRenameFilesIn(di);
    }
}
```

Though this will not handle duplicates names as Steven pointed out.