# Changing FileNames using RegEx and Recursion

Tags: c#, regex, file, renaming

I'm trying to rename files that my program lists as having "illegal characters" for a SharePoint file importation.  The illegal characters I am referring to are: ~ # % & * {} / \ | : <> ? - ""

What i'm trying to do is recurse through the drive, gather up a list of filenames and then through Regular Expressions, pick out file names from a List and try to replace the invalid characters in the actual filenames themselves.

Anybody have any idea how to do this?  So far i have this: (please remember, i'm a complete n00b to this stuff)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.smith\Desktop\~Test Folder for [SharePoint] %testing", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.Write(file + "\r\n");


        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);



        string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/:<>?|\"-]+ *";
        string replacement = " ";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.smith\Desktop\~Test Folder for [SharePoint] %testing", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.smith\Desktop\~Test Folder for [SharePoint] %testing\File_Renames.txt");
        foreach(string fileNames in fileDrive)
        {

        string sanitized = regEx.Replace(fileNames, replacement);
        sw.Write(sanitized + "\r\n");
        }
        sw.Close();



    }






}
```

So what i need to figure out is how to recursively search for these invalid chars, replace them in the actual filename itself.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think he just means rip them out

Comment: does the regex do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working recursively with files and directories, many times it's easier to use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class and it's members instead of the static methods.  There is a pre-built tree structure for you, so you don't have to manage that yourself.

[GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=VS.100).aspx) returns more DirectoryInfo instances so you can walk the tree, while [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=VS.100).aspx) returns [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=VS.100).aspx) objects.

This guy [created a custom iterator](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/08/15/214864.aspx) to recursively yield file info, which when you combine it with your existing regex work, would complete your solution.

Comment: i took a look at the custom iterator link.  where do i pass in the directory i want to drill into?

Comment: `GetFilesRecursive(dirInfo);` -- just pass a root dirInfo

Answer (score 1):

File.Move() effectively renames files. Basically, you'll just need to

```
File.Move(fileNames, sanitized);
```

inside the latter loop.

*ALERT* - possibly there'll be duplicate file names, so you'll have to establish a policy to avoid this, like appending a counter at the end of the `sanitized` variable. Also, apply a proper exception handling.

PS: Certainly, you don't need to search for characters like `:\*`.

Comment: Do i need to put an if/else statement in here?  Or if the file has no invalid characters, it'll automatically skip it?

Comment: @yeahumok, you may indeed compare `fileNames` with `sanitized` to avoid an unnecessary call to `File.Move()`. However, pay attention to duplicates (like, `#File.txt` and `~File.txt` will be named `File.txt`), and check for access permissions, disk space, and other IO exceptions.