# How to make a multiple files with 1 path?

Tags: c#, string, path

How to make a variable in a path in c#? For like creating a user register/login/stats.

```
string UserName = "";

string path = @"c:\File\File\" + UserName + ".text";
```

I know this doesn't work, maybe does anybody know how to do it else, I search around and never found a solution to get a path like this.

I hope somebody will solve it!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You can totally make a filename this way.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: How can I delete the invaled chars out of the UserName???

Comment: Please do not ask you question more than one times!

This is another question that you first ask. Please close this Question and open a new one [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Btw: [How to clean a FileName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825433/c-sharp-remove-invalid-characters-from-filename)

Comment: np I found it out by myself ty anyways.

Comment: well nice. Than please close this question with marking you correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use / (slashes) instead of \ (backslashes) or you can escape the backslash adding another backslash behind it:

```
string path = "c:\\File\\File\\"+ Username + ".text";
```

Comment: so you're saying that adding \ to every single \ and removing the @ will solve the hole thing with the variable in it?

Comment: I tested it and it says A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `Login.PlayerName'

Comment: If the `UserName` contains [invalid path characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) no function for creating or using files will accept this string and both of this is ok with `"\\"` oder `@"\"` it meens the same just another way to write it

Comment: could you give an example, I don't really understand how I should put it.

Answer (score 0):

That way is absolutly OK for simple concating strings. There are other ways like

[`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) function

or the

[`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class

This is all absolutly OK but if you will be absolutly sure that you create a vaild Path use

[`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that doesn't work is because of the escape characters. Any of the following will work;

```
string path = "c:\\File\\File\\"+ Username + ".txt"; // escape first slash, second appears in string
string path = @"c:\File\File\"+ Username + ".text"; // take literal string, escape sequences included
string path = "c:/File/File/"+ Username + ".text"; //forward slash is not an escape
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [get an array of invalid file name characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx)

```
char[] invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();

foreach (char ch in invalidPathChars)
{
   Username = Username.Replace(ch.ToString(), "");
}
```