# Remove Special characters from file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to remove special characters from file, I tried following code based on this [example](http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2013/11/c-remove-invalid-filename-characters.html), it is generating few errors. I need this code to work for asp.net webform based application.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        // your code goes here

        var file_name = GetValidFileName("this is)file<ame.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(file_name);
        private static string GetValidFileName(string fileName) {
            // remove any invalid character from the filename.
            return Regex.Replace(fileName.Trim(), "[^A-Za-z0-9_. ]+", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code on & output [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/FzpqfC)

Comment: What are the errors actually generated?

Comment: Error is listed here http://ideone.com/FzpqfC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626562/284240

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have put `private static string GetValidFileName` in `public static void Main()` and in C# is not allowed. Just simple change the code as follow and it will work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
    // your code goes here

    var file_name = GetValidFileName("this is)file<ame.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(GetValidFileName(file_name));

    }
    private static string GetValidFileName(string fileName) {
        // remove any invalid character from the filename.
        String ret = Regex.Replace(fileName.Trim(), "[^A-Za-z0-9_. ]+", "")
        return ret.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked but file have has white space `this isfileame.txt` how can i remove white space from file name.

Comment: Edited answer. I've used String.Replace instead of regex to remove whitespace only because it's more easy and readble

Answer (score -1):

string newName = UploadFile.FileName.Replace("&", "and");

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type a File Name:");
char[ ] invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();

string? FileName = Console.ReadLine();
if( FileName != null )
{
   string OutputFileName="";
   
   for (int i = 0; i < FileName.Length; i++)
   {
      char c = FileName[i];

      if (! invalidChars.Contains(c))
      {
         OutputFileName += c;
      }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Output :");
   Console.WriteLine(OutputFileName);
}
```