# How to incorporate a variable into a URI?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Basically I'm trying to put a result of a query into a file path, into the image source.

Updated code. Now I actually get the string I want but I still have trouble with interpolating it into the Uri constructor.

```
 Random rand = new Random();
            var nrand = rand.Next(1, 4);

            using (var db = new DungeonContext())
            {
                var query = db.Rooms.Where(b => b.RoomId == nrand).Select(b => b.RoomName);
                foreach(string name in query)
                {
                    nameOfRoom = name;
                }
            }
```

Somehow I have trouble setting images dir as Resources since I'm missing advancent properties for this folder.

```
roomScreen.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"/images/{nameOfRoom}.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Making Uri relative seemed to stop throwing exceptions, but the intended effect does not happen.

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887924/invalid-uri-the-format-of-the-uri-could-not-be-determined answer your question?

Comment: What is the value of `nameOfRoom`and where does the error come from, and when? Is it at compile, build, package or run time? I'm going to guess that you have a space in the value of `nameOfRoom` and the failure is at runtime?

Comment: the exception is System.UriFormatException
more pricesly: "{Incorrect URI indentification: can't detrmine the URI indetification format} " I'm paraphrasing a bit since I don't have english langage packk installed on this instance of VS. As for the exact vale of nameOfRoom, they're supposed to be either 1NE, 2NE, or 3NE

Comment: I haven't yet set them to Resource. I was thinking about it but I tried first with the method I was currently doing.

Comment: they are in the apllication directory. If I'm not being to specific I'm sorry, I'm not sure what's the correct way of calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're creating the URI is correct. The trouble is that you're trying to use what is likely meant to be readable text (the name of a room) in a URI and as a flle name. You didn't specify what `nameOfRoom` is, so I can't tell exactly why it's invalid.

There are ways around it. You could look at this answer which explains how to [remove invalid characters from a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356077/remove-special-characters-from-file-name).

But the best solution is not to have the problem. Don't use the name of the room as a file name. Your question indicates that a room has an ID, which is apparently an integer. Using that instead would be much easier:

```
using (var db = new DungeonContext())
{
    room = db.Rooms.Where(b => b.RoomId == nrand);
}
```

and then

```
roomScreen.Source = new BitmapImage( new Uri($"/images/Room{room.RoomId}.png"));
```

---

If you want to use your code as-is, that's possible. When you do this:

```
nameOfRoom = db.Rooms.Where(b => b.RoomId == nrand).ToString();
```

you're calling `ToString()` on what is presumably a `Room` class. Unless you override that method, the result will always be the name of the class. (So it would be the same for every room.)

If you overrode the `ToString` method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Room{RoomId}";
}
```

then calling room.ToString() would return "Room1" or "Room2", etc.

String interpolation calls `ToString()`, so in that case you could just do

`roomScreen.Source = new BitmapImage( new Uri($"/images/{room}.png"));`

That works. One downside is that it's not explicit. Someone reading that line of code might not know that `Room.ToString()` is also the value used to create a file name. You might also want to use the `ToString()` method differently.

If you wanted to be really explicit and clear, you could create an extension method like this:

```
public static class RoomFileNameExtensions
{
    public static string GetImageFileName(this Room room)
    {
        return $"Room{room.RoomId}.png";
    }
}
```

Now the `Room` class isn't responsible for knowing how file names are created. You could do this:

`roomScreen.Source = new BitmapImage( new Uri($"/images/{room.GetImageFileName()}"));`

You can use that both when creating the file and when reading the file. It ensures that both operations will determine the file name the same way.

Comment: well NameOfRoom is a string. Sorry for forgetting to mention it.

And I'm using its name because I'm also planning to use it as an identifier for the rooms features.
e. g. a room with the name 1NE has: 1 door, is normal, and is empty.

Also I might have wrote the Linq statment wrong, because I wasn't trying to get the RoomId prop, but other prop called RoomName.

Comment: I know (it comes from calling `ToString()`. But it still depends on what that string is. You could also leave it coded exactly as it is, and override `ToString()` on the room class so that it returns a valid string. But if the ID uniquely identifies the room, and the name of the file needs to uniquely identify the file, it could make sense to just use the ID.

Comment: sorry for all this mess with my question. I figured out what I had problems with and worded it better. now my main question was regarding the URI constructor and I'm not sure how I can use interpolated string in the constructor since it returns errors for invali characters. I might not have understood what you meant, and that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: to clarify, does the folder containing the images actually needs to be named "resouces"?

Comment: It was just an example. I tried to use details from your question. The same applies regardless of the folder name.

Comment: understandable. continuing from my other question did I use invalid argument in Uri? should I have provided the full path, i.e. starting from the disk?

Comment: There are multiple answers to that. I don't know what the actual URI was because I don't know what the string was. You can use the debugger to see what the string is. It's also good to look at the documentation for .NET framework classes. You can highlight the `Uri` class and press F1, or google "Uri class .NET".

Comment: thanks for the help. I managed to figure out the issue by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I needed to do was add UriKInd.RelativeOrAbsolute to the constructor.

Comment: It sounds like the solution you found doesn't relate to the question. The way you include text in a URI doesn't change depending on whether it's absolute or relative.

Comment: @ScottHannen Well it fixed my issue. And I think it wasn't working correctly not because I interpolated the string wrong, but because the path was invalid and by changing its path value it fixed everything. If you think my answer doesn't answer the question. I could just leave it unanswered.

Comment: The idea is to make sure it helps the next person. If someone else is trying to figure out how to incorporate a variable into a URL, and then they google and find this, will it answer their question?

Comment: @ScottHannen I guess I phrashed my question inaccuretly.

Answer (score -1):

If it's in the project directory, utilizing the `System.IO.Path` namespace comes to mind - something like

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, $"/images/{nameOfRoom}.png")
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can use this somewhere.