# Illegal characters in path while saving file

Tags: c#, asp.net, illegal-characters

Hi I m getting this error when I save a file in asp.net. I have put my application inside a folder containing space in the name.

```
Illegal characters in path. 
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. 
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) 
at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) 
at MyApp.Localization.LocalizationHelper.GetDefaultFilePath(String filepath) in D:\!  sf02_jan09_I\MyApp.Localization\Helper\LocalizationHelper.cs:line 36 
at Localization_Language.Save(String filePath, List`1 lstResDef) in d:\!  sf02_jan09_I\MyApp\Modules\Language\LanguageManager.ascx.cs:line 810
at Localization_Language.imbUpdate_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in d:\! sf02_jan09_I\MyApp\Modules\Language\LanguageManager.ascx.cs:line 743
```

When I remove the space from !sf02_jan09, it works..how do i handle saving file in this scenario?

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames  If the space is the problem include your file name inside "". Eg "c:\file name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

....in D:!

It's the exclamation point!

Answer (score 3):

space is not an illegal character - I suspect your problem is something else:

[MSDN: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i was looking for a list of reserved characters i could replace out.

Answer (score 0):

Meybe you should do some input validation on file names with illegal characters, instead of trying to change the name of the file?