# Python SpellCheck str object has no attribute read

Tags: python-3.x, spell-checking

Trying to get this spellchecker I came across online to work, but no luck. Any help Would be appreciated. Original code from http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

```
import re, collections, codecs

def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower()) 

def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model

file = codecs.open('C:\88888\88888\88888\88888\8888\A Word.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')

NWORDS = train(words(file.read()))

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def edits1(word):
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in splits if b]
    transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in splits if len(b)>1]
    replaces   = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in splits for c in alphabet if b]
    inserts    = [a + c + b     for a, b in splits for c in alphabet]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def known_edits2(word):
    return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) if e2 in NWORDS)

def known(words): return set(w for w in words if w in NWORDS)

def correct(word):
    candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
    return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\8888\8888\8888\8888\88888\SpellCheck.py", line 11
    file = codecs.open('C:\888\888\888\8888\88888\A Word.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's do something try this...
get a string value '\x' and try to do something to it
or try

```
string('\x.....')
```

Returns your error right?

So if you have a string defined say

```
x = string('\y\o\u \c\a\n \n\e\v\e\r \c\h\a\n\g\e \t\h\i\s \i\n \p\y\t\h\o\n')
```

Than you are just out of luck. 
It will be a bummer if the user decides to type a '\' as any character of the input.

To fix the problem you could try using some looping or recursive code like:
[How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames)

Answer (score 0):

`C:\88888\88888\88888\88888\8888\A Word.txt` - that's the strangest path I've seen this year :)

Try replacing it with `C:\\88888\\88888\\88888\\88888\\8888\\A Word.txt`