# DateTime as file name

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I need to create some log files with a name like this:
HH:mm_dd-MM-yyyy.log

I've tried to convert DateTime & DateTime.Now like this but the compiler encounters the next error:

```
The given path's format is not supported.
```

Code i've tried:

```
#1
var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string format = "HH:mm_dd-MM-yyyy";
string datetime = currentDateTime.ToString(format);
File.Create("Log/GameLog/"+datetime+".log");
#2
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm_dd-MM-yyyy");
File.Create("Log/GameLog/"+datetime+".log");
```

In this couple of cases the same error was raised by the compiler...
So in the end, my question is, how can i use datetime as a file name?

Comment: and btw, if you want all the log files to be order by date, use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` then all files from the same day will be always stick together

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the `:` character, you can't use that in a file name

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Widows Operating System does not allow following special characters in `filename`.

```
/ \ : * ? " < > |
```

so you need to Replace colon `:` with some other character (either with `_` or with `-`)

Try This:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing some of the characters you are returning with format and then add them in on at a time to see which is causing the problem.

My guess is it maybe the : character causing you a problem

also check this post which may help.

[How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames)

regards