# Unzipping with ExtractToDirectory method distorts non-latin symbols

Tags: c#, encoding, localization, zip, archive

I have several folders with files, some folders contain non-latin symbols in their names (russian in my case). This folders are sending to zip archive (by windows explorer) in "D:\test.zip".
Then I execute [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Hh485723%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

```
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"D:\test.zip", @"D:\result");
```

and it successfully unzip all content, but all non-latin symbols turn into something wrong.

For example, instead of **"D:\result\каскады\file.txt"** I got **"D:\result\Є бЄ ¤л\file.txt"**.

Default encoding of my system is *windows-1251* which I verified by involving `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")` into third parameter of [`ExtractToDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh875102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and getting the same result. I also tried *UTF-8*, but got another artifacts inside path (**"D:\result\��᪠��\file.txt"**). Trying *Unicode* return me message about not supported encoding.

When I create same archive through the code by executing [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"D:\zipdata", @"D:\test.zip");
```

everything then unzipping fine with the same line of code as in the top of the question, even without specifying particular encodings.

The question is: how to get correct encoding from archive for applying it in `ExtractToDirectory` method, in respect that in real task archive comes from external source and I can not rely on wherether it created 'by hands' or programmatically?

**Edit**
There is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407717/zipfile-extracttodirectory-illegal-characters-in-path) where also non-latin symbols (chinese) cause problems, but this fact was given like resolution of question, whereas this is exactly problem for my situation.

Comment: The fact that it works when you create the archive yourself strongly suggests that the issue is simply that the original archive you are extracting was created using a text encoding different from any that you've tried so far. Unfortunately, your details here are far from complete and are insufficient for anyone else to diagnose your problem. You should contact the author of the original archive and find out what encoding was actually used, so you can specify the correct one; barring that, you'll have to do make some informed guesses until you get the right one.

Comment: (Seeing the incorrectly-decoded text does give you some information: you can use that to determine what the originally-encoded text data is, and then you can use those bytes to try to find a text encoding that, when decoded using that encoding, returns the Cyrillic alphabet characters you expect. If it's not a Unicode encoding, then you probably just need to find the appropriate Cyrillic-compatible code page that would be used on a Cyrillic-configured computer.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks in advance, what information can I supply to complete details about problem? In question example, unzipping was successfull only for archive created by **code**, but *not* for **manually** created archive in the same machine by explorer (rigth click -> Send to -> zip archive). So, my own machine create zip with some encoding, differs from any encoding I tried for unzipping. Such problem can be solved by trying all possible encodings programmatically, but how can I get correct encoding from system information or/and from archive itself if possible?

Comment: _"how can I get correct encoding from system information or/and from archive itself"_ -- I doubt you can. ZIP archives don't support arbitrary code pages; frankly, it seems like a bug in whatever tool was used to create the archive (i.e. Windows Explorer in your case) that UTF8 isn't used when non-Latin characters are needed/used. You might have some success using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage` to determine the current code page for your system, which you can then use when opening the archive.

Comment: Barring just inspecting the machine in question (per `CurrentCulture` object), given that you are expecting Cyrillic characters, you might try code page 1251 or 28595 
(two of the more common Cyrillic code pages). You can find a full list of supported code pages [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.encoding(v=vs.100).aspx) (just search for "Cyrillic").

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks, I just enumerated through `Encoding.GetEncodings()` with unzipping on each iteration in different folders and got single positive match with 866 codepage, which is also equals `OEMCodePage` as you referred. Seems like we resolved all moments except getting encoding info from archive file itself (which would be the best source-independent solution for archive unzipping), but I'm not seeing any solution for this, so you can write separate answer about `OEMCodePage` for me to be able to mark it as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no formally standardized ZIP specification. However, the de facto standard is [the PKZIP "application note" document](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.3.TXT), which as of 2006 documents only code page 437 ("OEM United States") and UTF8 as legal text encodings for file entries in the archive:

> D.1 The ZIP format has historically supported only the original IBM PC character 
>   encoding set, commonly referred to as IBM Code Page 437.  This limits storing 
>   file name characters to only those within the original MS-DOS range of values 
>   and does not properly support file names in other character encodings, or 
>   languages. To address this limitation, this specification will support the 
>   following change.
>
> D.2 If general purpose bit 11 is unset, the file name and comment should conform 
>   to the original ZIP character encoding.  If general purpose bit 11 is set, the 
>   filename and comment must support The Unicode Standard, Version 4.1.0 or 
>   greater using the character encoding form defined by the UTF-8 storage 
>   specification.  The Unicode Standard is published by the The Unicode
>   Consortium (www.unicode.org).  UTF-8 encoded data stored within ZIP files 
>   is expected to not include a byte order mark (BOM).

In other words, it's a bug in any ZIP authoring tool to use any text encoding other than code page 437 or UTF8. Based on your experience, it appears Windows Explorer has this bug. :(

Unfortunately, the "general purpose bit 11" is the only official mechanism for indicating the actual text encoding used in the archive, and this allows only for either the original 437 code page or UTF8. Even this bit [was not supported by .NET until .NET 4.5](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/711235/system-io-ziparchive-zipped-only-utf-8-encoding). In any case, even since that time it is not possible for .NET or any other ZIP archive-aware software to reliably determine a non-standard, unsupported encoding used to encode the file entry names in the archive.

However, you *can*, if the source machine used to create the archive is known and available, determine the default code page installed on that machine, via the `CultureInfo` class. The following expression will return the code page identifier installed on the machine where the expression is executed (assuming the process hasn't changed its current culture from the default, of course):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage
```

This gives you the code page ID that can be passed to [`Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wzsz3bk3(v=vs.100).aspx) to retrieve an `Encoding` object that can then be passed to the appropriate `ZipArchive` constructor when opening an existing archive, to ensure that the file entry names are decoded correctly.

If you are unable to retrieve the actual text encoding from the machine that is the origin of the archive, then you're stuck enumerating the encodings, trying each one until you find one that reports entry names in a legible format.

As I understand it, Windows 8 and later can support the UTF8 flag in the ZIP archive file. I haven't tried it, but it's possible that such versions of Windows also *write* archives using that flag. If so, that would (one hopes) mitigate the pain of the earlier Windows bug.

Finally note that a custom tool could record the encoding in a special file entry placed in the archive itself. Of course, only that tool would be able to recognize the special file and use it to determine the correct encoding (the tool would have to open the archive twice: once to retrieve the file, and then a second time once the tool has determined the encoding). This is not an ideal solution and of course is no help for archives created by Windows Explorer. I mention it only for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your research! It is real disappointment that they didn't allocate 4 bytes for encoding id in zip header to solve such problems forever. And it seems like problem still not solved in windows 8.1 - I tried in virtual machine with same `OEMCodePage` and `Encoding.Default` as in my work machine (*866* and *windows-1251* respectively) and got the same results.

Comment: As for custom tool - it is possible just specify *UTF-8* in [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String, String, CompressionLevel, Boolean, Encoding)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh875104%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use this encoding for unzipping, but thanks for advice)

Comment: Re: custom tool: my point there is regarding how to actually embed in the archive itself the actual encoding used. Yes, you can specify the encoding when creating/opening the archive; but knowing _which_ encoding to use when opening the archive is not possible unless you do something extra (like storing a special file that contains this information). Of course, if you just always use UTF8, that's probably good enough. Anyway, glad I could help.