# Unzipping using c# with ExtractToDirectory and special symbols in file names in archive

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, system.io.compression.zipfile

## Hello.

I have an archive with 1 file only with next name: Pva=Pokus@#&τƒ².docx .But when i extract this file via c# code i.e. this method
`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName, destinationDirectory, encoding);`  i always get in output directory file with incorrect name. I tried all of encoding, but it does not working. I found that topick [Unzipping with ExtractToDirectory method distorts non-latin symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402791/unzipping-with-extracttodirectory-method-distorts-non-latin-symbols) but there is no naswer. TotalCommander and windows 11 unpacking it with properly names, but my code does not. What to do?
Any suggestions and help will be awesome.
Many Thanks

Comment: Why such a weird name. What would be the problem if you give it a normal name instead of a password-lookalike?

Comment: It is a bulk files import and user could give every names he only wants. And windows could do it and totalCommander could od it. too but c# could not ? why?

Comment: C# is not Windows. There are limitations on webservers and other operating systems like Linux etc. You will have to sanatize the user input.

Comment: What exactly is the incorrect name that you are getting?