# Can't create folder structure with variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a folder with a variable that can change, I am using

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory
```

When I hardcode a value like so:

```
var folder = @"C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\bot\random string here"
```

It creates that directory, but when I pass data to my method and try and use it like so:

```
var folder = @"C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\bot\" + 
 articlename.Replace(" ", "_");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

It doesn't create it nor break. How can I use the variable to create a folder like that?

My `article` is a random string like "hello this is a article yadda"

Comment: More or less that should work. Sure you aren't seeing any exceptions?

Comment: Does your random string have any invalid file name characters in it?

Comment: Turns out I had illegal characters, I thought removing spaces may have stopped that from having illgel charatcers fixed now :)

Comment: But spaces are valid characters. You can see the reserved characters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions)

Comment: Spaces are valid path characters. You should use `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` instead. See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23182807/332528

Comment: Your example with spaces was the one that worked, so spaces weren't the problem... :)

Answer (score -1):

I solved by adding my paths together correctly as below

```
string path = root +"/"+ newfolder;
 if (!Directory.Exists(path))
 {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   // To move a file or folder to a new location:
   //System.IO.File.Move(fi.FullName, path);
 }
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, use `Path.Combine()`.